# Using regex to extract username from email address

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My string of text looks like this:

```
johndoe@domain.com (John Doe)
```

I need to get just the part before the @ and nothing else. The text is coming from a simple XML object if that matters any.

The code I have looks like this:

```
$authorpre = $key->{"author"};
$re1 = '((?:[a-z][a-z]+))';

if ($c = preg_match_all ("/".$re1."/is", $authorpre, $matches))
{
    $author = $matches[1][0];
}
```

Sometimes the username might have numbers or an underscore before the @ symbol, which is where the regex stops it seems.

Comment: Your regexp has an outer capturing group `()` and an inner non-capturing group `(?:)`. The inner non-capturing group may be unnecessary given that you want to capture what is inside. The `[a-z]` means capture a lower-case letter. The `[a-z]+` means capture 1 or more lower-case letters. So effectively your expression means capture anything that is 2 or more lower-case letters long. If you were to put a `^` at the very front of your expression it would ensure that matching only takes place from the _beginning_ of the text.

Comment: Won't be very fun, I fear. Some example strings you may want to test: `"John Doe"@example.com (John Doe)`, `"(>'.')>"@example.com (John Doe)`, `foo@[192.168.2.1] (John Doe)`, `^.^@example.com (John Doe)`, `"a@b@c"@example.com (John Doe)"`. Yes, those are all valid e-mail addresses :-)

Comment: @Johannes: `"a@b@c"@example.com (John Doe)` is really allowed? That really complicates things...

Comment: Welbog: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address ... you can quote the local-part which allows for characters otherwise not allowed.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The regular expression that will match and capture any character until it reaches the `@` character:

```
([^@]+)
```

That seems like what you need. It'll handle all kinds of freaky variations on e-mail addresses.

---

I'm not sure why [Ben James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189179/ben-james) deleted his answer, since I feel it's better than mine. I'm going to post it here (unless he undeletes his answer):

> Why use regex instead of string functions?
>
> ```
> $parts = explode("@", "johndoe@domain.com");
> $username = $parts[0];
> ```

You don't need regular expressions in this situation at all. I think using `explode` is a much better option, personally.

---

As [Johannes Rössel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/johannes-rossel) points out in the comments, e-mail address parsing is rather complicated. If you want to be 100% sure that you will be able to handle any technically-valid e-mail address, you're going to have to write a routine that will handle quoting properly, because both solutions listed in my answer will choke on addresses like `"a@b"@example.com`. There may be a library that handles this kind of parsing for you, but I am unaware of it.

Comment: depending on how intense your regex can get, i personally like explode function. Fits well with what your looking for.

Comment: What's with the e-mail address `"a@b"@example.com`?

Comment: The fun never ends with source routes in e-mail addresses: http://www.remote.org/jochen/mail/info/address.html

Comment: @Johannes: Is the `@` character allowed in the domain portion of the address? Because, if not, both solutions could still work as long as they look for the *last* `@` character instead of the first.

Comment: Taking everything before the *last* `@` should work, yes. Unless Jane Doe comes with the cool idea to use `"j@nedoe"@example.com (J@ne Doe)` ...

Comment: @Johannes: Good catch. So, last `@` character before the first `(` character, then. Does anyone have a counterexample for that one?

Comment: @Greg: No, because of Johannes' counterexample of the address `"a@b"@example.com`.

Comment: Maybe `"j@n(= doe"@example.com (J@ne Doe)`? :D

Comment: (Ok, this is getting weird. I'm beginning to understand why e-mail addresses get much more restricted by many e-mail providers.)

Comment: @Johannes: Damn it. Does PHP have any built-in or third-party e-mail parsing libraries?

Comment: Not that I know of. Still, I think your idea is perfectly fine for roughly 100 % of all e-mail addresses *in use*. But I still want to have one of those addresses one day to pester applications with poor validation routines :-)

Comment: @Johannes: So do I... Just as a subtle protest to whoever it is who came up with such a complicated grammar for e-mail addresses.

Comment: However, if you just search for the first *unquoted* `@` and take everything before that, it should work.

Comment: @Johannes: Yeah, but deciding whether a character is quoted or not is bordering on the upper limit of regular expressions' domain. It's possible, sure, but it won't be pretty.

Comment: Oh, and quoting can also be done with a backslash ... Yes, it's definitely unpretty :-)

Comment: To bypass the @ problem just count the number of items in the array. If it's 2 then the email does not contain any extra @. If it has more you just have to get all the items in the array except the last on and join them with a @ :D

Comment: @AntonioCS: That works too, unless there's a `@` in the parenthetical string like Johannes' example `"j@n(= doe"@example.com (J@ne Doe)`. Counting the `@`s will lead you to believe that `ne Doe` is the domain.

Comment: Your regexp snippet "[^"]*" does not correctly match a quoted string, since a quoted string may contain escaped quote characters. For instance, "contains \"quotes\"" <weird@address.example> is a valid address. It would be better with "(?:[^"]|\\.)*".

Comment: @markusk: This is exactly why I wouldn't use a regular expression in this situation. I'm just going to pull it down. People who want to see it can look in the revision history.

Comment: What about using the limit in the explode function? Something like this

`implode(explode('@',$email,-1),'');`

That would give you everything before the last '@'.

Comment: Would need to implode with `@` so that any non-final occurrences are restored:
`implode(explode('@',$email,-1),'@');`

Answer (score 7):

@OP, if you only want to get everything before @, just use string/array methods. No need complicated regex. Explode on "@", then remove the last element which is the domain part

```
$str = '"peter@john@doe"@domain.com (John Doe)';
$s = explode("@",$str);
array_pop($s); #remove last element.
$s = implode("@",$s);
print $s;
```

output

```
$ php test.php
"peter@john@doe"
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this variant is a bit slower than explode(), but it takes only one string:

```
$name = preg_replace('/@.*?$/', '', $email);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$email  = 'name@example.com';
$domain = strstr($email, '@');
echo $domain; // prints @example.com

$user = strstr($email, '@', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0
echo $user; // prints name
?>
```

[source](http://php.net/strstr)

Comment: Faster than using regex!

Comment: This will fail on `"()<>[]:,;@\\"!#$%&'-/=?^_\`{}| ~.a"@example.org` and other emails with quoted `@` locals.  Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38787343/2943403

Answer (score 4):

I used [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$email_username = preg_replace('/@.*/', '', $_POST['email']);
```

Comment: This will fail on `"()<>[]:,;@\\"!#$%&'-/=?^_\`{}| ~.a"@example.org` and other emails with quoted `@` locals.  Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38787343/2943403

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion:

```
$email = 'johndoe@domain.com';
$username = substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'));

// Output (in $username): johndoe
```

Comment: This will fail on `"()<>[]:,;@\\"!#$%&'-/=?^_\`{}| ~.a"@example.org` and other emails with quoted `@` locals.  Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38787343/2943403

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with `$author = str_replace(strrchr($authorpre, '@'), '', $authorpre);`

Answer (score 2):

You could start by using [`mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses`](http://php.net/manual/function.mailparse-rfc822-parse-addresses.php) to parse the address and extract just the address specification without any display name. Then, you could extract the part before `@` with the regexp `(.*)@`.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
list($username, $domain) = explode('@', $email . "@"); // ."@" is a trick: look note below
```

With this solution you'll have already populated two variables with email address parts in one row.

`."@"`: This is made to avoid in short critical errors with the list command and ensure that `explode` will produce at least two variables as needed.

Comment: This will fail on `"()<>[]:,;@\\"!#$%&'-/=?^_\`{}| ~.a"@example.org` and other emails with quoted `@` locals.  Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38787343/2943403

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is still looking in 2020 ..here's the regex that can pick the text before the '@'

```
^(\S+)(?=@)
```

Comment: This will not match valid address like: `" "@example.org`, [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples)

Answer (score 0):

Basic example:

```
    $email = "linuxUser@IsGrand.com";
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        list($user, $domain) = explode('@', trim($email) . "@");
    } else {
        echo "Unable to get account info ....";
    }
```

Complex Example:
Something like this to populate Firstname and Last name fields:

```
1) valid email ?  if yes get the two parts  user and domain.
2) else set to something default etc.
3) use the email address if we don't have a decoded value.
```

Code:

```
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        list($fname, $lname) = explode('@', trim($email) . "@");
    } else {
        $fname = "Xdefault";
        $lname = "Ydefault";
    }

    $fname = (!empty($decoded['firstname'][0]))  ? $decoded['firstname'][0] : $fname ;
    $lname = (!empty($decoded['lastname'][0]))  ? $decoded['lastname'][0] : $lname ;
```

Comment: This will fail on `"()<>[]:,;@\\"!#$%&'-/=?^_\`{}| ~.a"@example.org` and other emails with quoted `@` locals.  Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38787343/2943403

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to suggest a non regex solution here as it may be useful in most cases:

```
strstr('n.shah@xyz.co', '@', true)
```

output:

> *n.shah*

Comment: This is a exact copy of munjal's answer which was posted many years earlier.