# Using grep to find all emails

Tags: linux, grep

How to properly construct regular expression for "grep" linux program, to find all email in, say /etc directory ?
Currently, my script is following:

```
grep -srhw "[[:alnum:]]*@[[:alnum:]]*" /etc
```

It working OK - a see some of the emails, but when i modify it, to catch the one-or-more charactes before- and after the "@" sign ...

```
grep -srhw "[[:alnum:]]+@[[:alnum:]]+" /etc
```

.. it stops working at all

Also, it does't catches emails of form "Name.LastName@site.com"

Help !

Comment: Here's a better regex to match e-mail addresses, although it requires Perl: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: If you're not using `(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_``{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_``{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])` you're doing it wrong. http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: @thomas that's just ridiculous!!! :D @glowcoder yours is bad enough but... that's the most convoluted regexp i've seen in 10+ years of using them :D

Comment: Both @thomas and @glowcoder have stumbled onto the sad truth that email addresses are really complex.  A lot more complex than most people realize.  However, most email addresses are rather simple ;)

Comment: I should have put a smiley in my remark; it was not intended to be taken seriously. There is no need for such stringent validation. You're not going to know whether the address is valid until you actually send e-mail to it...

Answer (score 29):

Here is another example

```
grep -Eiorh '([[:alnum:]_.-]+@[[:alnum:]_.-]+?\.[[:alpha:].]{2,6})' "$@" * | sort | uniq > emails.txt
```

This variant works with 3 level domains.

Comment: This one worked REALLY well for me.  Include `uniq -c` to get a count of all the email addresses!  Sweet!

Comment: This is a bad answer.  It converts `fred+smith@company.com` to `smith@company.com`, dropping the `fred+`.  The use of plus signs is very common with Gmail.  Many other special characters are also allowed in the official email address  spec (RFC 5322).

Comment: +1 , good pointer.

Here is a slight variant "grep -Eiorh '([[:alnum:]|\._.-]+@[[:alnum:]_.-]+?\.[[:alpha:].]{2,6})' "$@" * | sort | uniq > emails.txt" which also considers '.' in the email

Comment: This is good but all of these match: `fuU@jRpfhW.pI` `t@K6B.zzz` `A1uSO@H.qVBDV` `5@ebUQai3._a.LI`

Answer (score 6):

`grep` requires most of the regular expression special characters to be escaped - including `+`. You'll want to do one of these two:

```
grep -srhw "[[:alnum:]]\+@[[:alnum:]]\+" /etc

egrep -srhw "[[:alnum:]]+@[[:alnum:]]+" /etc
```

Comment: Sometimes, logins have underscores, so I'd add an underscore to the expression: "[[:alnum:]|_]\+@[[:alnum:]]\+"

Comment: This is a bad answer.  It includes many false positives.  For example, `x@x@x@x@x` passes your regex.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson This was more about explaining how to fix what the OP had (bad escaping) than providing a perfect regex. Certainly you could reduce the false positives if this isn't just for something quick and dirty, but at that point you pretty much always want to use something other than regex. And if you are doing something quick and dirty, usually better to have false positives than false negatives. So... perfect? Definitely not? Bad? Not really.

Answer (score 5):

I modified your regex to include punctuation (like .-_ etc) by changing it to

```
egrep -ho "[[:graph:]]+@[[:graph:]]+"
```

This still is pretty clean and matches... well, most anything with an @ in it, of course. Also 3rd level domains, also addresses with '%' or '+' in them. See http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/grep/grep_8.html for a good documentation on the character class used.

In my example, the addresses were surrounded by white space, making matching quite easy. If you grep through a mail server log for example, you can add < > to make it match only the addresses:

```
egrep -ho "<[[:graph:]]+@[[:graph:]]+>"
```

@thomas, @glowcoder and @oedo all are right. The RFC that defines how an eMail address can look is quite a fun read. (I've been using GNU grep 2.9 above, included in Ubuntu).

Also check out zpea's version below, it should make for a less trigger-happy matcher.

Comment: Good answer! However, it's probably better to use something like `[[:alnum:]._%+-]` instead of `[[:graph:]]` because`[:punct:]` (which is included in `[:graph:]`) contains the `@` character - which might lead to problems in matching - alongside some other characters unlikely to be found in email addresses.

Comment: This is a bad answer.  It includes many false positives.  For example, `x@x@x@x@x` passes your regex.

Comment: Chris is right, I wouldn't use this myself for serious tasks, like sanitizing user input. However, matching all *possible* (RFC-compliant) eMail addresses is hard, as others have pointed out. For the OP's question, Chris's `x@x@x@..` example might well be irrelevant. As always with regex, choose wisely.

Answer (score 4):

I have used this one in order to filter email address **identified by 'at' symbol and isolated by white spaces** within a text:

```
egrep -o "[^[:space:]]+@[^[:space:]]+" | tr -d "<>"
```

Of course, you can use *grep -E* instead *egrep* (extended grep). Note that *tr* command is used to remove typical email delimiters.

Answer (score 3):

`grep -E -o -r "[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}" /etc`

This is adapted from an answer that is not mine originally, but I found it super helpful. It's from here:

http://www.shellhacks.com/en/RegEx-Find-Email-Addresses-in-a-File-using-Grep

They suggest:

`grep -E -o -r "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" /etc`

But it has certain false positives, like '+person..@example.com' or 'person@..com', and the whitespace constraints miss things like "mailto:person@example.com" (not *technically* an email but contains one); so I tweaked it a little bit.

(Do what you want with the options to grep, I don't know them very well)

Answer (score 1):

This recursive one works great for me :

```
grep -rIhEo "\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\b" /etc/*
```

Comment: So you don't want to find my email address *@example.com then? (Yes * is a valid character) - and no I'm not at example.com, I changed that part :P

Comment: you're right, Characters ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^ _ ` { | } ~ are allowed : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-email-address , -1 ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to mention that a slight variation of this works great for grabbing mentions from things like twitter tweets:

`grep -Eiorh '(@[[:alnum:]_.-]+)' "$@" * | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: What's with the use of both `"$@"` and `*`? You want one or the other, but not both. Anyway, this answer doesn't really belong here -- maybe post a new question instead? ISTR there are a few more twists to Twitter handles.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work but picks up file names with **@**

```
egrep -osrwh "[[:alnum:]._%+-]+@[[:alnum:]]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" ~/.thunderbird/
```

Answer (score 0):

> **I Bet There Are No Best Base Regex Exists Than This One**

```
egrep -o "[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\+\%\-]{1,}\@[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\+\%\-]{1,}\.[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\+\%\-]{1,}"
```

It Will Not Leave A Single Email From The Garbage But The Thing You Must Have To Do Is, Extract If Something Same As Email But Not Email, Like
`home_mobile@1x.png`, Either It Needs Manual Lookup Or Make My Mentioned Regex More Specific Towards What You Want
Add More Special Characters But There Are No Base Regex Exists Which Is Better Than This

Comment: Extra Special Char Added  '%'

Comment: Char '-' Must Be Last - I Think It Will Get Improved And Best By Best Through Me