# Using grep cmd to filter by first letter, @, and "."

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have a file (testdata.txt) with many email addresses and random text. 
Using the grep command:

I want to make sure they are email addresses and not text, so I want to filter them out so that only lines with "@" are included.

I also want to filter them out so that only email addresses that start with the letter A-M or a-m are shown and have a period separating the first name and last name.

Eg. john.doe@gmail.com
However, johndoe@gmail.com would be included.

Lastly, I want to get the count of all the email addresses that follow these rules.

So far I've only been able to make sure they are email addresses by doing

```
grep -c "@" testdata.txt
```

.

Using the grep cmd I also want to check how many email addresses have a government domain ("gov").

I wanted to do a check that it has a @ sign in the line and that it also contains gov. However, I don't get the answer I want when I do any of the following.

```
grep -c "@\|gov" testdata.txt   I get the amount of lines that have a @ not @ and gov
grep -c "@/|gov" testdata.txt   I get 0
grep -c "@|gov" testdata.txt    I get 0
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898463/using-grep-to-find-all-emails

Comment: quite a lot of words with no sample input file and expected output shown.. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , separate your different parts of questions with line breaks or number them.. or better stick to one problem  per question.. a well formed question often gives you a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going bottom-up with your questions.

You are using `grep` in its *Basic regular expressions* mode. In this mode `\|` means **OR**, `|` means the symbol **|**, and `/|` mean the symbols **/|**.

If you were looking for emails in the .gov domain, you would probably be looking for a sequence starting with **@** and followed by symbols that are permitted in an Internet domain name and the symbols **.gov**, or **.GOV**, or **.Gov**.

Borrowing from [another post on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27059450/1328439) you would end up with something like

```
   grep -c "@[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9.-]*\.\(gov\|Gov\|GOV\)"
```

skipping another 5 possible spellings for the top level domain, e.g. **GoV**.
However I would use the `-i` switch that means *ignore case* to simplify the expression

```
   grep -ci "@[a-z0-9][a-z0-9.-]*\.gov"
```

Now you were not very clear regarding the use of dots separating parts of the name:

> I also want to filter them out so that only email addresses that start with the letter A-M or a-m are shown and have a period separating the first name and last name.  Eg. john.doe@gmail.com However, johndoe@gmail.com would be included.

So I will not touch this part.

Finally You could use *range expressions* to filter the addresses that start with the letters **A**-**M**

```
   grep -ci "[a-m][a-z0-9._%+-]*@[a-z0-9][a-z0-9.-]*\.gov"
```

**Please note** that this is not an implementation of the Internet Message Format RFC 5322 [address specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4) but only an approximation used mainly for didactic purpose. Never leave not fully compliant implementations in production code.