# Why won't my bash script list emails in the file it creates?

Tags: bash

This bash script has a simple premise for now, recursively look through a directory, take every file from that directory, and from those files look for patterns that match email addresses, take those email addresses, sort them and then count the amount of times they appear, and sort them again.

Take those sorted emails and then with the head script, print the top emails according to the variable PUNISHED.

The directory is via the second argument, and if no directory is chosen then it simply runs through the current directory.

like this.

./myscript   20  /usr/home/AlabasterTenRing

Here is the code.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

PUNISHED=$1
VENOM= $2

echo >> topemails.txt

for files in ./${VENOM}/**/*; do
    if [ -f "${files}" ] ; then
        <"$files" tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]' \
            | grep -i -o '[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]\ + @[A-Za-z0-9.]\ + .[A-Za-z]\{2,4\}' \
            | xargs -n 1 \
            | sort \
            | uniq -c \
            | sort -nr > topemails.txt
    fi
done
echo "The top \"${PUNISHED}\" emails are"
head -$PUNISHED topemails.txt
```

What ends up happening instead is that topemails.txt prints just as intended, but the number '1' is all that appears in it.

What could I do differently?

Comment: You overwrite the file on each iteration. You can use `>>` in the loop to append (or even better, simply redirect the entire loop)

Comment: Side Comments: check if 'xargs' is needed. The 'grep' command will print one token per line, so in theory, no need for xargs. Also, 'grep' is using case insensitive match (-i), therefore no need to use both A-Z and a-z in the patterns.

Comment: Also 'VENOM= $2' will not work if '$2' is non-empty. Space not allowed between '=' and value.

Comment: If you code still does not work, consider sharing sample input (few lines) data from one of your files

Comment: @thatotherguy when you say use >> in the loop to append, can you elaborate? Also, what do you mean redirect the entire loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easier way to reproduce your problem:

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
  echo "$i" > file
done
```

You're expecting `file` to contain:

```
1
2
3
```

Instead it contains:

```
3
```

This is because `>` truncates and overwrites the file each time, so you'll only get results from the last iteration.

You can either have each iteration *append* rather than *overwrite*:

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
  echo "$i" >> file
done
```

Or just redirect the whole loop, so that everything it outputs will be collected in the file:

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
  echo "$i"
done > file
```

Comment: I used your fixes, this is progress but now only the directory name appears in topemails.txt, none of the files that should be recursively run through even so much affect the script.

Comment: @MATT_BOOTY It does if you put e.g. `a + @b + cde` in a file. `foo@example.com` won't affect the result since the regex doesn't match it

Comment: Wait, my regex doesn't match foo@example.com? But that's exactly what I want to be matching.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898463/using-grep-to-find-all-emails) for various suggestions on how to match emails with `grep`. You'll find scripting much easier if you write and test small parts of individual commands every step of the way, rather than writing a whole script and then try to debug all issues simultaneously. `grep -i -o '[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]\ +'` should be matching `hello` but doesn't, so that narrows the problem down considerably (in this case due to the space)

Comment: I don't think it's the grep anymore, I changed it to one that had worked, even removed tr, it didn't work at all. It only lists the directory that I inserted as an argument as opposed to recursively looking through the directory for files.

Comment: @MATT_BOOTY When you say "It only lists the directory that I inserted as an argument", do mean "I'm getting the error `./myscript: line 6: /usr/home/AlabasterTenRing: Is a directory`"? If so, that's because you have a space after the `=` on line 6. If you fix that and get zero matches, it's because you're looking at `.//usr/home/AlabasterTenRing/**/*` instead of `/usr/home/AlabasterTenRing/**/*`

Answer (score 1):

Something I think is equivalent to your script, but it depends on which grep favor is used. You can use grep to scan recursively and skip the loop, since you seem to scan all files anyway.

```
#!/bin/bash

PUNISHED=$1
VENOM=$2

echo "The top ${PUNISHED} emails are"
grep -Eroh "[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}" "./${VENOM}" \
    | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' \
    | sort \
    | uniq -c \
    | sort -nr \
    | head -n $PUNISHED
```

Domain names can have longer top levels than 4 characters now, but I left the 4 inthe regex.