# regular expression escape for grep in bash

Tags: regex, bash, grep

What is the best way to convert a regular expression to a string which can be accepted by grep/sed in bash?

for example, [given the following regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/AB6g1R/1)

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

bash does not like it (and thus this regular expression cannot be used in grep)

```bash
$ echo "(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])"
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

$ echo '(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])'
>
> ^C
```

i assume that the regular expression needs to be escaped, but i didn't find any good tool that can do it for me.

any idea how can i let grep use this regular expression in bash?

Comment: If i am not wrong, you are trying to use this regex to capture emails. In this aspect you could consider to use `grep -E -o "your regex here" file.txt` - Also check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898463/using-grep-to-find-all-emails

Comment: You need to quote the entire thing. Your string has a `"` inside it which ends the quotation early and messes things up. Escape the quotes inside the string with `\"` so that the entire string is quoted.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou as you can see, i cannot surround the regex in double\single quotes. that is why i open the case. i wonder how can this be done :)

Comment: @Verpous i know it needs to be escaped, that is what i wrote. i am after a command\tool that will do that for me without human interaction.

Comment: @Mr. Where does the regex arrive from then, and how do you intend to use it? Can you edit your post with a more concrete example of your use case that illustrates this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's combine two useful Bash features to get there.

First, you can completely avoid the need to escape a string using a Here Doc with quoted delimiter (ie. `<<"separator"`). For example, you can write something like this:

```
cat<<"EOF"
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
EOF
```

Second, by wrapping that Here Doc into a function, you can easily grab this to a variable. From that point, you can directly provide that variable to grep or sed.

For example:

```
function regex() {
cat<<"EOF"
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
EOF
}

echo "email@test.com" | grep -P $( regex )
```

Note that your regex require a Perl-compliant regex engine (aka. PCRE). Escaped hexadecimal sequences inside character class expressions (ie. `[\x70-\x7f]`) are not supported by most other engines, which means that the previous sequence would match on these characters: `\`, `x`, `7`, `0-\`, `x`, `7`, `f`).

Comment: maybe it escapes the string, yet it affects the regex and thus the regex does not capture any email address

Comment: Indeed. I modified explanation for how to use the regex directly with `egrep`, without the `printf '%q'` part.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to know is how to enclose a string with single
quotes if the string includes single quote(s) inside.
Let me simplify the string as an example:

```
O'Reilly
```

As you know, a backslash does not work to escape the single quote within single quotes:

```
str='O\'Reilly'         # wrong
```

Instead you can say:

```
str='O'\''Reilly'
```

It may look weired but it is just a concatenation of `'O'`, `\'` and `'Reilly'`.

```
'O'      ... single quoted string "O"
\'       ... literal single quote
'Reilly' ... single quoted string "Reilly"
```

Then you can assign a variable to your regex with:

```
regex='(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'\''*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'\''*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])'

# echo "$regex"

grep -P "$regex" <<< 'email@example.com'
```

Please note the two single quotes are handled as the example above.