# removing "@something" with preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex

In the stack-overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303184/how-to-remove-email-addresses-and-links-from-a-string-in-php) , it was explained that you can remove emails with this code:

```
$pattern = "/[^@\s]*@[^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*/";
$replacement = "[removed]";
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

This removes stuff like johndoe@gmail.com   - how do I modify the regular expression so that I remove something like @johnDoe from a chunk of text?

I really don't understand regular expression that well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$pattern = "/@[^@\s]*/";
```

---

In `[^@\s]`:

- `\s` stands for any space character
- `[@\s]` stands for a character group, containing `\s` (i.e. space) and the `@` character. it matches either `@` or `\s`
- `[^@\s]` stands for the character group that is *not* `@\s`
- afterall, `[^@\s]` matches a single character that is not `@` character or `\s` (i.e. spaces)

`*` after it stands for the previous token (i.e. `[^@\s]` here) can repeat zero or more times. Hence, `[^@\s]*` matches string of any length as long as it does not contain `@` or `\s`

---

As a side note, your link give a much-simplified regex for matching e-mails. [The perfect way of matching e-mails are no simple matter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: Thanks! that was exactly what I was looking for. And thanks for the explanation of the regex code