# HTML5 Email input pattern attribute

Tags: html, forms, email-validation, html-input

I’m trying to make a html5 form that contains one email input, one check box input, and one submit input.
I'm trying to use the pattern attribute for the email input but I don't know what to place in this attribute. I do know that I'm supposed to use a regular expression that must match the JavaScript Pattern production but I don't know how to do this.

What I'm trying to get this attribute to do is to check to make sure that the email contains one @ and at least one or more dot and if possible check to see if the address after the @ is a real address. If I can't do this through this attribute then I'll consider using JavaScript but for checking for one @ and one or more dot I do want to use the pattern attribute for sure.

The pattern attribute needs to check for:

1. Only one @
2. One or more dot
3. And if possible check to see if the address after the @ is a valid address

An alternative to this one is to use a JavaScript but for all the other conditions I do not want to use a JavaScript.

Comment: Why not just use an email input type?

Comment: The HTML5 email input treats `foo@bar` as valid. While it may be *technically* valid (for example, `foo@localhost` is a valid email), for most real world use cases, it's not going to work, and users may end up not getting emails as they've missed the .com (or whatever) off

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27000682/1256925) for another solution, which also includes patterns for other types of inputs.

Comment: Spec: [HTML 5.2 spec section 4.10.5.3.6. The pattern attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-pattern-attribute)

Comment: Relevant:  https://www.facebook.com/groups/2344226875800424?multi_permalinks=3712570102299421&hoisted_section_header_type=recently_seen

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This is a dual problem (as many in the world wide web world).

You need to evaluate if the browser supports html5 (I use Modernizr to do it). In this case if you have a normal form the browser will do the job for you, but if you need ajax/json (as many of everyday case) you need to perform manual verification anyway.

.. so, my suggestion is to use a regular expression to evaluate anytime before submit. The expression I use is the following:

```js
var email = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
```

This one is taken from http://www.regular-expressions.info/ . This is a hard world to understand and master, so I suggest you to read this page carefully.

Comment: One thing to note here is that the HTML5 form validation email pattern will allow for all of the valid email address formats. That includes local domain email addresses such as foo@bar without a TLD. Most regex patterns do not cater for the full list of valid cases. (such as the case above)

Comment: There is no a silver bullet regex for email, since the emails can be:
"ABC"<user@server> or at least tag+user@email.com
Last thing is tag, when actual address is prepended with a tag that allow to group the messages. eg. project-x+bob.smith@company.com will be delivered to bob.smyth@company.coma ddress

Comment: The regex for e-mail here is completely broken and should not be used.  Top level domains can be way outside of 2 to 4 characters, and that's just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: To fix it not to fail on capital letter just add /i flag like this: /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i

Comment: It does not support the current standard for valid email addresses, which allows for international unicode characters to support non-latin languages and diacritics: https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc6530

Answer (score 108):

I had this exact problem with HTML5s email input, using Alwin Keslers answer above I added the regex to the HTML5 email input so the user must have .something at the end.

```
<input type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" />
```

Comment: This regex is completely broken.  Do not use it or you will be throwing out a lot of good addresses.

Comment: Sidenote: Using `type="email"` and the pattern in the latest version of Firefox (44,45) failed. I had to use `type="text"` in order for the pattern to work.

Comment: Be careful with this one because it do not let emails from new top-level domains (such as .asia or .club)  though

Comment: What Sergey said and also this comment from above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601647/html5-email-input-pattern-attribute#comment34529001_8897615

@HackbalTeamz - it means end of line or string, see also: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=regex+cheat+sheet&t=hj&ia=cheatsheet&iax=1

Comment: the `type="email"` does the basic job already in modern browsers. So using `pattern` attribute just overrides the default behavior.

Comment: It should be noted that as of 08/2023, the longest TLD is 7 letters (.website).  So, to make sure you include all possibilities, the end of the pattern should be `+\.[a-z]{2,7}$`

Comment: @Brad I believe you should escape `-` signs, like this: `[a-z0-9._%+\-]+@[a-z0-9.\-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$`
Look at other improvements in this question as well - there are some more improvements, like longer TLD support or case insensitivity.

Comment: type="email" does the job I think we use pattern for text type in this case.

Answer (score 68):

Unfortunately, all suggestions except from B-Money are invalid for most cases.

Here is a lot of valid emails like:

- günter@web.de (German umlaut)
- антон@россия.рф (Russian, рф is a valid domain)
- chinese and many other languages (see for example [International email](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email) and linked specs).

Because of complexity to get validation right, I propose a very generic solution:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+" title="Invalid email address" />
```

It checks if email contains at least one character (also number or whatever except another "@" or whitespace) before "@", at least two characters (or whatever except another "@" or whitespace) after "@" and one dot in between. This pattern does not accept addresses like lol@company, sometimes used in internal networks. But this one could be used, if required:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+" title="Invalid email address" />
```

Both patterns accepts also less valid emails, for example emails with vertical tab. But for me it's good enough. Stronger checks like trying to connect to mail-server or ping domain should happen anyway on the server side.

BTW, I just wrote angular directive (not well tested yet) for email validation with `novalidate` and without based on pattern above to support DRY-principle:

```
.directive('isEmail', ['$compile', '$q', 't', function($compile, $q, t) {
    var EMAIL_PATTERN = '^[^@\\s]+@[^@\\s]+\\.[^@\\s]+$';
    var EMAIL_REGEXP = new RegExp(EMAIL_PATTERN, 'i');
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel){
            function validate(value) {
                var valid = angular.isUndefined(value)
                    || value.length === 0
                    || EMAIL_REGEXP.test(value);
                ngModel.$setValidity('email', valid);
                return valid ? value : undefined;
            }
            ngModel.$formatters.unshift(validate);
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(validate);
            elem.attr('pattern', EMAIL_PATTERN);
            elem.attr('title', 'Invalid email address');
        }
    };
}])
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text" is-email />
```

For B-Money's pattern is "@" just enough. But it decline two or more "@" and all spaces.

Comment: Have been searching for decent solution for a while now, this works !! Thanks Dude !

Comment: When I paste günter@web.de into input type="email" pattern="[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+", then the input gets tagged :invalid.

Comment: @JenniferMichelle that's because even `input type="email"` doesn't do validation right. But depending on your use case it could be still fine.

Comment: I started with the proposed pattern for email extraction from json and finally I finish with this pattern: [^@\s\"\.]+@[^@\s\"]+\.[^@\s\"]+

Comment: This opens up to way too many other invalid characters in an email. Email address `&*()@!$%^.com` is valid in this case.  There are ways to match unicode, this is not it. Here's a good start: https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/. Also, this is a poor use of `title` attribute. To a screen reader, that field will always read "Invalid email address" when perhaps it isn't. The title attribute isn't meant to be a validation message alone. Consider "Enter a valid email address" instead as the `title`.

Comment: This accepts tlds with one char. Can it be changed to 2+ chars? Thanks.

Comment: Try `[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s][^@\s]+` or `[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]{2,64}`

Answer (score 25):

In HTML5 you can use the new 'email' type: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html

For example:

```
<input type="email" id="email" />
```

If the browser implements HTML5 it will make sure that the user has entered a valid email address in the field. Note that if the browser doesn't implement HTML5, it will be treated like a 'text' type, ie:

```
<input type="text" id="email" />
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the email type input will validate "s@s", which, of course, is an invalid email address. So, this is the reason why an email input should have a pattern.

Comment: Of course is `s@s` an absolutely valid email address. Furthermore, even `"   "@s`is a valid email address.

Comment: No need for overkill. If you want a better version,  check if it contains one dot after @. Example format: a@a.a

Comment: @AliMertCakar But me@subdomain.domain.com is a valid email address, isn't it?

Comment: @BobRodes Yes, for example companies use mails like (@)marketing.company.com as every subdomain has different "reputation" (meaning if your subdomain is flagged your other (sub)domains won't be). So you should check for @, minimum one dot after @, and minimum 1 letter for each part.

Comment: @AliMertCakar It seems I misunderstood your "check if it contains one dot after" to mean "one and only one dot after" when you meant "at least one dot after." Thanks for clarifying; that makes sense now. I suppose it might also be a good idea to make sure that none of the dots are adjacent and that the ending character isn't a dot.

Comment: @BobRodes but ali..mert@gmail.com is valid adress too. as most mail services ignore dots on the left side :)

Comment: @AliMertCakar Ignore dots on the left side? So bob.rodes@bobrodes.com is the same as bobrodes@bobrodes.com?

Comment: yes for general mail services like gmail. try sending a mail to your gmail account with dots on the left side. mert@gmail.com is the same as m.e.r.t@gmail.com

Comment: @AliMertCakar I didn't know that. Interesting! Thanks for explaining. I guess there are more specific services that use dots, like my father's Notre Dame email was  rodes.1@nd.edu. That's the one I was thinking of.

Answer (score 15):

This is the approach I'm using and you can modify it based on your needs:

```
^[\w]{1,}[\w.+-]{0,}@[\w-]{2,}([.][a-zA-Z]{2,}|[.][\w-]{2,}[.][a-zA-Z]{2,})$
```

Explanation:

1. We want to make sure that the e-mail address always starts with a word:

   **^[\w]**

A word is any character, digit or underscore. You can use [a-zA-Z0-9_] pattern, but it will give you the same result and it's longer.

2. Next, we want to make sure that there is at least one such character:

   ^[\w]**{1,}**
3. Next, we want to allow any word, digit or special characters in the name. This way, we can be sure that the e-mail won't start with the dot, but can contain the dot on other than the first position:

   ^[\w]{1,}**[\w.+-]**
4. And of course, there doesn't have to be any of such character because e-mail address can have only one letter followed by @:

   ^[\w]{1,}[\w.+-]**{0,}**
5. Next, we need the @ character which is mandatory, but there can be only one in the whole e-mail:

   ^[\w]{1,}[\w.+-]{0,}**@**
6. Right behind the @ character, we want the domain name. Here, you can define how many characters you want as minimum and from which range of characters. I'd go for all word characters including the hyphen **[\w-]** and I want at least two of them **{2,}**. If you want to allow domains like **t.co**, you would have to allow one character from this range **{1,}**:

   ^[\w]{1,}[\w.+-]{0,}@**[\w-]{2,}**
7. Next, we need to deal with two cases. Either there's just the domain name followed by the domain extension, or there's subdomain name followed by the domain name followed by the extension, for example, **abc.com** versus **abc.co.uk**. To make this work, we need to use the **(a|b)** token where **a** stands for the first case, **b** stands for the second case and **|** stands for logical OR. In the first case, we will deal with just the domain extension, but since it will be always there no matter the case, we can safely add it to both cases:

   ^[\w]{1,}[\w.+-]{0,}@[\w-]{2,}**([.][a-zA-Z]{2,}|[.][a-zA-Z]{2,})**

This pattern says that we need exactly one dot character followed by letters, no digits, and we want at least two of them, in both cases.

8. For the second case, we will add the domain name in front of the domain extension, thus making the original domain name a subdomain:

   ^[\w]{1,}[\w.+-]{0,}@[\w-]{2,}([.][a-zA-Z]{2,}|**[.][\w-]{2,}**[.][a-zA-Z]{2,})

The domain name can consist of word characters including the hyphen and again, we want at least two characters here.

9. Finally, we need to mark the end of the whole pattern:

   ^[\w]{1,}[\w.+-]{0,}@[\w-]{2,}([.][a-zA-Z]{2,}|[.][\w-]{2,}[.][a-zA-Z]{2,})**$**
10. Go here and test if your e-mail matches the pattern: https://regex101.com/r/374XLJ/1

Comment: Thanks for the highly detailed information. But according to this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) **example@s.solutions** is a valid email, but your pattern doesn't match it.

Comment: @Piet You're right, but that's by design. In the step number 6, I stated that for the domain name, we will use at least two characters **{2,}** and if you want to allow domains like **t.co** or your **s.solutions**, you would have to allow only one character from this range **{1,}**. If you edit the pattern accordingly, your domain will match.

Once you understand the construction principles of patterns, you can alter them any way you like :)

Here's the altered pattern for your e-mail: https://regex101.com/r/374XLJ/2

Comment: Just being pedantic here so : an email address must not exceed 254 characters.
Adding that check too would make it a more complete example.

Comment: Great, thank you for the pattern and explanation. I'm going to link this to an answer from angular.

Comment: Regex patterns offer the shortcut * for {0,} and + for {1,} and you can use \. to match a period character so you don't have to define a character range. Since you need a domain name and extension in any case, you do not need to split these in your (a|b) token but you can simply add the optional domain name in between. Thus, shorten your regex to `^[\w]+[\w.+-]*@[\w-]{2,}(\.[\w-]{2,})?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$`. The shortcut ? stands for {0,1}, so it is optional but may not occur more than once.

Comment: None of those will work because the HTML5 `pattern` regex attribute is anchored by default. Working patterns are required to match (and consume) the entire string.

Answer (score 10):

A simple good answer can be an input like this:

**2021 UPDATED & Support IE10+**

`^(?![_.-])((?![_.-][_.-])[a-zA-Z\d_.-]){0,63}[a-zA-Z\d]@((?!-)((?!--)[a-zA-Z\d-]){0,63}[a-zA-Z\d]\.){1,2}([a-zA-Z]{2,14}\.)?[a-zA-Z]{2,14}$`

```css
input:not(:placeholder-shown):invalid{
  background-color:pink;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px red;
}
/* :not(:placeholder-shown) = when it is empty, do not take as invalid */
/* :not(:-ms-placeholder-shown) use for IE11 */
/* :invalid = it is not followed pattern or maxlength and also if required and not filled */
/* Note: When autocomplete is on, it is possible the browser force CSS to change the input background and font color, so i used box-shadow for second option*/
```

```html
Type your Email:
<input 
  type="email"
  name="email"
  lang="en"
  maxlength="254"
  value=""
  placeholder="example@domain.com"
  autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off"
  autocomplete="on"
  required=""
  inputmode="email"
  pattern="(?![_.-])((?![_.-][_.-])[a-zA-Z\d_.-]){0,63}[a-zA-Z\d]@((?!-)((?!--)[a-zA-Z\d-]){0,63}[a-zA-Z\d]\.){1,2}([a-zA-Z]{2,14}\.)?[a-zA-Z]{2,14}">
```

According to the following:

- Resources about **standard Email format**: [What characters are allowed in an email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address)
- Resources about **standard HTML Email input attributes**:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email

- **Maximum length** of domain in URL (254 Character)
- Longest possible **Subdomain**(Maybe =0-64 character), **Domain** (=0-64 character), **First Level Extension**(=2-14 character), **Second Level Extension**(Maybe =2-14 character) as @Brad motioned.
- Avoiding of **not usual but allowed characters** in Email name and just accepting usual characters that famous free email services like Outlook, Yahoo, Gmail etc. will just accept them. It means accepting just : **dot (.)**, **dash (-)**, **underscore (_)** just in between **a-z** (**lowercase**) or **A-Z** (**uppercase** - just because it is common - thanks to [Badri Paudel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898251/badri-paudel)) and **numbers** and also **not accepting double** of them next to each other and maximum **64 characters**.

**Note**: Right now, longer address and even Unicode characters are possible in URL and also a user can send email to local or an IP, but i think still it is better to not accepting unusual things if the target page is public.

Explain of the regex:

1. `(?![_.-])` not started with these: _ . -
2. `((?!--)[a-zA-Z\d-])` accept a till z and A till Z and numbers and - (dash) but not --
3. `((?![_.-][_.-])[a-zA-Z\d_.-])` from a till z lowercase and A till Z uppercase and numbers and also _ . - accepted but not any kind of double of them.
4. `{0,63}` Length from zero till 63 (the second group `[a-zA-Z\d]` will fill the +1 but just do not let the character be _ . -)
5. `@` The at sign
6. `(rule){1,2}` this rule should exist 1 or 2 times. (for Subdomain & Domain)
7. `(rule)?` or `((rule)|)` not exist or if exist should follow the rule. (for Second Level Extension)
8. `\.` Dot

**Note:** For being more strict about `uppercase` you can remove all `A-Z` from the pattern.

**Note:** For being not strict about `Persian/Arabic numbers` `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩` `۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹` you can add `\u0660-\u0669\u06f0-\u06f9` next to all `\d` in the pattern.

Try the RegEx: https://regexr.com/64kjf

**Note:** Using `^...$` is not necessary in input pattern, but for general RegEx testing will be needed. It means start / end of the string should be same as the rule, not just a part.

Explaining of attributes:

`type="email"` or `type="text"` (`email` In modern browsers will help for the validation also it don't care spaces in start or end for the validation or getting value)

`name="email" autocomplete="on"` To browser remember easy last filled input for auto completing

`lang="en"` Helping for default input be English

`inputmode="email"` Will help to touch keyboards be more compatible

`maxlength="254"` Setting the maximum length of the input

`autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off"` Turning off possible wrong auto correctors in browser

`required=""` This field is required to if it was empty or invalid, form be not submitted

`pattern="..."` The regex inside will check the validation

---

`\w`=`a-zA-Z\d_` so:

Lightest version
`(?![_.-])((?![_.-][_.-])[\w.-]){0,63}[a-zA-Z\d]@((?!-)((?!--)[a-zA-Z\d-]){0,63}[a-zA-Z\d]\.){1,2}([a-zA-Z]{2,14}\.)?[a-zA-Z]{2,14}`

Comment: Seems like it works. Tested many examples. But, your solution doesn't accept uppercase letters, especially frontend shouldn't restrict on that as email can be converted to lowercase at backend or using JS before sending to backend.

Comment: @badri-paudel Thank you, that is a wise look. actually i wanted to it be lightly strict, because even there is another problem too for my language and it is **Persian/Arabic numbers** that look same for users but are different in Unicode so **\d** not supporting them. But still because generally uppercase is more common, i will add it. Also **inputmode="email"** will help in android for not starting with uppercase.

Answer (score 9):

```
<input name="email" type="email" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,63}$" class="form-control" placeholder="Email*" id="email" required="">
```

This is modified version of above solution which accept capital letter as well.

Comment: how can I escape the `\.` character in the pattern? It is causing the line to break with an ""Unrecognised escape character" message. I'm doing this in Razor `@Html.TextBoxFor`

Comment: This RegEx fails for addresses at a TLD.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to write a whitepaper about Email-Standards, then use my following example which just introduce a well known CSS-attribute (**text-transform**: lowercase) to solve the problem:

If you do want the **data not to reach the server side as lower case value**, then you should go this way:

```html
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}" style="text-transform: lowercase" placeholder="enter email here ..." required />
```

---

If you do want the **data to reach the server side as lower case value**, then you should go this way:

```js
  const emailElmtRegex = new RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}');
document.getElementById("entered").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("send").innerHTML = ""

function lower() {
    let emailElmt = document.getElementById("email");
    document.getElementById("entered").innerHTML = "Entered: " + emailElmt.value;
    emailElmt.value = emailElmt.value.toLowerCase();

    if (emailElmtRegex.test(emailElmt.value)) {
        document.getElementById("send").innerHTML = "Send: " + emailElmt.value;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("send").innerHTML = ""
    }
}
```

```css
input[type=email]#email {
   "text-transform: lowercase
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h3>Client Side to Server Side - Simple Email validation!</h3>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}" placeholder="enter email here ..." required oninput="lower()" />

<p id="entered">Entered:</p>
<p id="send">Send:</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This only affects how the address is displayed by the browser. Uppercase letters will still be sent to the server on submission.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Fixed!

Answer (score 8):

```
<input type="email" pattern="^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$">
```

[Demo - Test the email input](https://codepen.io/maikyabelico/pen/BaovgzM)

Comment: The last part should be `{2,63}` to support TLDs like `.solutions`

Answer (score 6):

**You probably want something like this.  Notice the attributes:**

- required
- type=email
- autofocus
- pattern

`<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" id="EMAIL" placeholder="your@email.com" autofocus required pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" />`

Comment: this pattern is allowed to type email without ".com" , "your@email" only

Comment: @VanyDiahP It's entirely valid to have e-mail addresses on a TLD.

Answer (score 5):

#### I used following Regex to satisfy for following emails.

```
abc@example.com # Minimum three characters
ABC.xyz@example.com # Accepts Caps as well.
abce.xyz@example.co.in # Accepts . before @
```

#### Code

```
<input type="email" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]{3,}@[a-zA-Z]{3,}([.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}|[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,})" />
```

Comment: Hi@t.co is a valid email address and fails with your regular expression.

Comment: Hey, I have added minimum number of charectors to be 3 before @, That is  the reason its failing. `"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]{2,}@[a-zA-Z]{1,}([.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}|[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,})"`, This should work for you

Comment: Ok - so why don't you remove the minimum number of characters before the @ then so your answer is correct. I'll upvote you if you do. :-)

Comment: For me 3 is minimum, I find it ok to have minimum of three charectors. Practically Its hard to find email with 2 or 1 charectors. Thanks.

Comment: Works fine, but indeed: changing 3 to something else is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

One more solution that is built on top of w3org specification.
Original regex is taken from [w3org](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120320/input.email.html).
The last "***** Lazy quantifier" in this regex was replaced with "**+** One or more quantifier".
Such a pattern fully complies with the specification, with one exception: it does not allow top level domain addresses such as "**foo@com**"

```
<input
    type="email" 
    pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+"
    title="valid@email.com"
    placeholder="valid@mail.com"
    required>
```

Answer (score 4):

Updated 2018 Answer

Go here http://emailregex.com/

Javascript:

`/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/`

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" required />
```

documentation http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html

Comment: All normal peoples use latest version of major browsers, so this is solution will work. I see no reason to focus on people using hopelessly outdated technologies. Especially since the question was about html5.

Answer (score 3):

The following regex pattern should work with most emails, including russian emails.

`[^@]+@[^\.]+\..+`

Comment: It's possible to have an e-mail address at a top-level domain, so no dot in the host part of the address is required.

Answer (score 1):

Email Validation Regex using Html5 with angular as below

```
<div class="item">
      <p>Email Address<span class="required">*</span></p>
      <input type="email" name="to" id="to" placeholder="Email address" tabindex="6" required
        [(ngModel)]="pancard.email" #to="ngModel" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._-]*@[a-zA-Z]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}" />
        <div class="alertField" *ngIf="to.invalid && (to.dirty || to.touched)">
          <div *ngIf="to.errors?.['required']">Email is required </div>
          <div *ngIf="to.errors?.['pattern']">Invalid Email Id.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It is working example..

Comment: I would consider removing the `{2,3}` section of the regex as nowadays there are tld that are longer than this (think of .agency as example). Plus this would not consider valid domains with extensions like .co.uk

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following regex which gives the same result as Chrome Html email input validation.

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*
```

You can test it out on this website: 
[regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score -1):

```
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$
```

Answer (score -2):

```
pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]{1,40}[@]{1}[a-z]{1,10}[.]{1}[a-z]{3}"

<input type="email"  class="form-control" id="driver_email" placeholder="Enter Driver Email" name="driver_email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]{1,40}[@]{1}[a-z]{1,10}[.]{1}[a-z]{3}" required="">
```

Comment: You can indent code by 4 spaces to change its formatting. There is a button for that on top when you edit post.

Comment: This pattern fails for many common TLDs.  Don't use it.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$"
```

Comment: This pattern fails for many common TLDs. Don't use it.