# Making a form pattern using the pattern attribute to validate an email

Tags: html

How do I make a pattern for an email address that is only valid if it contains at least one character, followed by an @ sign, followed by at least one character, followed by a period (.) followed by at least “co”. (So, “a@b.co” is an example of the “least valid” email address)

Comment: check out the similar thread dude, it might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601647/html5-email-input-pattern-attribute

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use regex to validate the email address. I suggest you look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) if you don't know about regular expressions. The expression for validating an email is this:

```
/^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/
```

You will have to validate it using JavaScript regex. Check that out [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml).