# HTML Email Validation after the @

Tags: html, forms, validation

Is it possible to require a "." after the "@"?

The `required` validation only forces an email to have some content after the "@", but I would like to require a "." to make the user type in ".com/.org/etc"

http://jsfiddle.net/X6Uuc/333/

[image]

Comment: Check the second answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601647/html5-email-input-pattern-attribute

Comment: I'm able to use type="email", but it allows the form to submit without having a ".com/.org/etc"

Comment: Yes. Check out parsley.js, its a more fully featured input validation library

Comment: FQDNs don't have to have a dot in them. It's unusual for someone to run an email address directly off a TLD but not unheard of (and more likely to happen with the recent massive influx of new TLDs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're relying on the `input[type=email]` you can also use the `pattern` attr:

I got theRegEx in the example below from the [W3C spec for the email input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html#input.email.attrs.value.single). The native pattern uses `*` in the last part then it's not required, I only changed it to `+`;

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+$" required />
  <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: This has more validation, but isn't turning valid when i type in a full email address: http://i.imgur.com/7Ir3Wn7.png

Comment: Yes it works, I need to have both `oninput="setCustomValidity('')" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter your full email address.')"`