# HTML5 input pattern for givenname.lastname@containsstring.domain

Tags: regex, html

I'm trying to validate an email input via HTML5 pattern.

The input field must follow this format:

```
givenname.lastname@simonsays.domain
```

In other words I need to check if there is a string of letters + a dot + another string of letters + must contain the string `simon`.

So far I've found

```
pattern=".*simon.+"
```

However, it only checks if the input contains `simon`.

Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601647/html5-email-input-pattern-attribute

Comment: You can trial-and-error your RegEx in https://regex101.com/ ,

It even has break-down explanation of what does your RegEx actually means

Comment: regex101.com is broken.

Comment: @sln What do you mean? It works for me.

Comment: Try `pattern="\S+\.\S+@\S*simon\S*\.\S+"`

Comment: Wow, thank you Wiktor! I've been struggling with this issue for quite a long time but now it works like a charm!

Comment: @Stephan Ok, I posted the answer with some explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
pattern="\S+\.\S+@\S*simon\S*\.\S+"
```

The pattern gets parsed as `/^(?:\S+\.\S+@\S*simon\S*\.\S+)$/` and matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing container group
- `\S+\.\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars, `.` and 1+ chars other than whitespace
- `@` - a `@` char
- `\S*` - 0+ non-whitespace chars
- `simon` - a literal substring
- `\S*` - 0+ non-whitespace chars
- `\.` - a dot
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `)` - end of the container group
- `$` - end of string.

HTML5:

```css
input:valid {
  color: black;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input pattern="\S+\.\S+@\S*simon\S*\.\S+" title="Please enter an email address with 'simon' in the domain name!" placeholder="name.surname@domain.com" value="my.name@some-simon-here.com" />
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

If you want to "controll" the dots in the pattern, replace `\S` with `[^\s.]` that matches any char but a whitespace and `.`.

Comment: Thank you for this very useful explanation!