# HTML form doesn't get validated

Tags: html

I am struggling to validate a simple form and i just cant figure what's wrong. Here is a simple example that doesn't validate:

```html
<form name="loginForm">
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required/>
  <input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

Comment: Look here: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/10/angular-6-reactive-forms-validation-example Also post the logic you are using in the .ts please

Comment: your code is working fine what is the issue ?

Comment: Make sure that you're not forget to import `FormsModule`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Email Input Pattern Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601647/html5-email-input-pattern-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `type="email"` will validate "a@b" which, of course, is an invalid email address.

You could use a pattern to validate the email address, like so:

```html
<form name="loginForm">
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$"/>
  <input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems ok. With your code. If you want to test if your form is ok you can add a form action to redirect user after the right submit of your form like this (with action = "newPage.html):

```
<body>
<form id="loginForm" action="newPage.html">  
    Your mail:
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required/>

    <input type="submit" value="Save form" />
</form>
```

So now to test, you have to create the "newPage.html" file with the body you want:

```
<body>
   <p>good submit</p>
</body>
```

If the new page appears, it's ok for your submit!