# pattern attribute does not work well in e-mail type field

Tags: html, email-validation

I need e-mail type field in HTML5 to validate e-mails containing also letters ñ and Ñ, so I created this input field:

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" 
data-val="true" data-val-email="El E-mail ingresado es incorrecto." 
data-val-length="El E-mail debe tener como máximo 80 caracteres." 
data-val-length-max="80" data-val-required="El campo E-mail es obligatorio." 
id="Email" name="Email" 
pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ.!#$%&amp;'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$" 
placeholder="E-mail" required="required" type="email" 
value="kacuña@domain.com">
```

Test address is kacuña@domain.com.

If I test that regular expression in https://regex101.com/ it works, but not in Chrome. It seems that Chrome does not recognize that attribute.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate [international email addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email). I'd suggest using a `text` field instead, with pattern.

An answer from a a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36379040/2819106) suggest using a more generic solution and I agree.

> ```
> <input type="text" pattern="[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+" title="Invalid email address" />
> ```
>
> It checks if email contains at least one character (also number or
>   whatever except another "@" or whitespace) before "@", at least two
>   characters (or whatever except another "@" or whitespace) after "@"
>   and one dot in between. This pattern does not accept addresses like
>   lol@company, sometimes used in internal networks. But this one could
>   be used, if required:
>
> ```
> <input type="text" pattern="[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+" title="Invalid email address" />
> ```
>
> Both patterns accepts also less valid emails, for example emails with
>   vertical tab. But for me it's good enough. Stronger checks like trying
>   to connect to mail-server or ping domain should happen anyway on the
>   server side.