# Azure AD B2C: susi user flow layout bug: invalid character in class in regular expression

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure B2C with standard susi user-flow.

The page layout version is 2.17.

We are using a custom HTML page, but I don't think the problem is related to that.

Please take a look at the screenshot:
There is pw present, but still it says to enter keyword.

Browser console shows error:
Unable to check <input pattern='^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'+^_`{}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'+^_`{}~-]+)*@(?:a-zA-Z0-9?.)+a-zA-Z0-9?$'> because the pattern is not a valid regexp: invalid character in class in regular expression

[image]

I would expect to not have any errors concerning the regex.

The whole layout experience is not fluid, like it is showing red error labels even when entering values.

Expectation is that error labels are only visible when there is really an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not valid. This leads to fully broken validation mechanism.

Make sure to correct you regex, try first removing it, and then start with a simple one until you got it like you want it. Somehow your shown regex above is altered by stackoverflows text editing chars, please move it into a code block, so we may help you.

Where do you have yours from?
Email validation can be excessive, see [HTML5 Email input pattern attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601647/html5-email-input-pattern-attribute)

Why not just use the HTML email element - this will use an official standard validation - s@s and "    "@x are actually valid emails addresses ..

Comment: Thank you, remy. > Where do you have yours from? I wish I knew! Guess it comes from the Microsoft B2C server, but it would be a rather huge error. I am not sure if it can be administered in the B2C somewhere. Still it confirms my suspicion that this breaks the validation.

Comment: Try to play around with your settings there - or directly file an issue with them