# Can there be an apostrophe in an email address?

Tags: email, email-validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What characters are allowed in email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-email-address)

I have an email address with an apostrophe in it and am wondering if that is valid?

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address the local part can contain an apostrophe.

Comment: I have a co-worker with an apostrophe in his last name, and it's valid in his email address.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Yes, according to [RFC 3696](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696) apostrophes are valid as long as they come before the @ symbol.

Comment: Not according to Google Mail. http://imgur.com/hX5W2T7  - I bet Gmail wont even accept emails with apostophes in them and to be hones in 25 years, since the days of Dial Up Buliten boards, I have not once seen an email with an apostophe.

Comment: Gmail does receive emails from addresses with apostrophes.

Comment: Google Mail will not let you create one with an apostrophe vs the question which is can a valid email address contain an apostrophe.

Comment: @ppumkin People *do* have email addresses with apostrophes. I see them not infrequently, and have had to fix bugs submitted by angry Hibernians.

Comment: This answer is woefully lacking in detail on what appears to be quite a complex issue when you delve in to it.

Comment: I think the real answer is "Yes, bit its a terrible idea to do it". Having an apostraphe sirname turns your name into an SQL injection device. Seriously. I've lost how count of how many sites crash due to the ' in my name over the years. Same too with email. My policy suggestion is ACCEPT email addresses with it, and REJECT attempts to create email addresses with it.