# Can't delete record from MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, where-clause, sql-delete

Trying to delete record from my database, but I get the error "Unknown column '' in 'where clause'".

```
private void deleteUser() {
    String query = "DELETE FROM user WHERE Name =" + tfemail.getText() + "";
    executeQuery(query);
    showUsers();
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: First use quotes around your values (or better prepared statements) and second don't store the password in plain text!!!

Comment: Print the string query and check what you are saving in.

Comment: Don't insert text from user into a SQL statement. It leaves the code susceptible to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, allowing the user to corrupt / destroy / steal your data. Use a `PreparedStatement`, or an equivalent helper method. It also prevents errors like this.

Comment: *but I get error "Unknown column '' in 'where clause'".* Provide: 1) precise value of `query` variable which causes error 2) complete and unchanged error message.

Comment: Prediction: no single quotes which must wrap the literal value inserted into the query text.

Comment: Unknown column 'Admin' in 'where clause'

Comment: As @Andreas mentioned you're about to make it vulnerable for SQL injections if simply wrapping the email argument with apostrophes. Especially if apostrophe is a part of the email address e.g. `johnny's_gift@mail.com`, and your query gets either syntactically broken causing SQL exceptions or exploited: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527180/can-there-be-an-apostrophe-in-an-email-address

Answer (score 1):

You can't write queries this way. Imagine someone put in the `tfemail` field this text:

```
"Joe' OR FALSE"
```

and let's see what that would do to your SQL query:

```
DELETE FROM user WHERE Name = 'Joe' OR FALSE;
```

bye, database!

Some dbs let you execute stuff on the server the db engine runs on. Which means this trick can be used to completely hack the machine or format the disk entirely. bye, entire machine.

This also means your `executeQuery` method *needs to be removed* - that abstraction ('here is some SQL, please run it') is rarely useful (as it cannot contain any user input), and entices you to write security leaks.

The solution is prepared statements:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM user WHERE Name = ?");
ps.setString(1, "Joe");
ps.executeUpdate();
```

This solves your problem, and does so safely - `ps.setString(1, "Joe' OR FALSE");` is now no longer an issue (the DB engine or JDBC driver guarantees that it will take care of the problem; the effect would be to delete the entry in your user table that literally reads "Joe' OR FALSE").

Furthermore, storing passwords in a database is not an acceptable strategy; the solution is e.g. bcrypt: Use a hashing algorithm designed specifically to store passwords.

Comment: This is how a good answer looks like: not simple "hey you've missed an obvious thing" but also an explanation preventing things that may lead to very bad things.

Answer (score -1):

```java
String query = "DELETE FROM user WHERE Name ='" + tfemail.getText() + "'";
                                             ^                         ^
                                             |___________add___________|
```

Comment: @Kevin399 Don't forget to mark your question as resolved with this answer.

Comment: No, don't. This is a horrible, _horrible_ answer. It seems to work, but it actually doesn't: __This will get your server hacked__. @Akina please delete or update this answer.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Everyone has the right to do as they want - including doing bad things. You have warned the author - that is enough. Smart will take into account. A fool is not a pity.