# EWS C# International Characters In Email address returning error

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm having issues using EWS to save an email address to a contact when the email address contains foreign characters.  In particular, the German umlaut is giving me issues.  The following is an example of an attempt to create a valid email address.  EWS throws back an error saying the email address isn't valid.  Can anybody help?  Thanks

```
Mailbox mailbox = new Mailbox("box@blah.com");
FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, mailbox);
Contact contact = new Contact(service);
contact.GivenName = "John";
contact.Surname = "Döe";

EmailAddress address = new EmailAddress();
address.Address = "JohnDöe@blah.com";
address.RoutingType = "SMTP";

contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = address;
contact.Save(folderId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does Exchange allow umlauts in email addresses?

[RFC 5321](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5321.txt), the governing spec for email addresses, doesn't allow them. See [this SO question on allowed email address characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-email-address) for more info.