# Is both pattern and type="email" used in conjunction an issue?

Tags: html, attributes

### HTML5 email type & patterns

Are there any issues, conflict or otherwise, between using both the new HTML5 `type` values (e.g. *email*, *tel*, etc.) in conjunction with the `pattern` attribute.

**I'm not referring to HTML5 browser compatibility—only the direct effect the new values for these attributes have when used in conjunction with the `pattern` attribute.**

I'll put a few examples in for clarity using `type="email"`

**A. Type attribute only.**

```
<input type="email">
```

**B. Only pattern attribute**

```
<input type="text" pattern="[email regex]">
```

**C. Email & Pattern attributes used together**

```
<input type="email" pattern="[email regex]">
```

I feel like you gain more semantic value with the new HTML5 type values; however, regex is much more controllable as email@localhost is valid via only the email value being used.

*If their's a duplicate, my apologies, I looked around but didn't see this particular question*

### EDIT

I found a mention of possible negative effects when using both in conjunction with each other. However, I'm unsure how credible the source is.

> As both ways of validating email addresses has their pros and cons it is up to you to decide which one to use. **You should not try to use them both at the same time as this might induce a clash in browsers that support both features.** Using type=”email” has the advantage that it is semantically correct both using the pattern attribute has the advantage that there are several easy-to-use polyfills on the web which ensures support for a greater range of audience.

[Source](http://www.html5-tutorials.org/form-validation/validating-email/)

Just be sure to test thoroughly if both are used in unison. I'll update the question if I find any negative side effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Necessity

The `pattern` attribute shouldn't be necessary on any browser which fully conforms to the HTML5 specification on how the various `type` states are implemented.

For example, this is how the `type=email` `input` element should be implemented:

> If the `multiple` attribute *isn't* specified...
>
> While the value of the element is neither the empty string **nor a single valid e-mail address**, the element is suffering from a type mismatch.
>
> If the `multiple` attribute *is* specified...
>
> The value attribute, if specified, **must have a value that is a [valid e-mail address list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address-list)**.
>
> — [HTML5 Specification's Email State (`type=email`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#e-mail-state-(type=email))

In really basic terms this means that the element's `value` will return empty if an empty string nor valid email address has been entered into it. This means that the browser should attempt to validate the email address where no `pattern` attribute is present. If the `pattern` attribute is present, *both* the browser and the specified regular expression would be taken into account.

### Usefulness

Despite not being necessary, you may still want to use the `pattern` attribute to only catch certain varieties of input. For instance, `admin@mailserver1` is a valid email address ([according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses)), and you may want to explicitly only allow email addresses which have a TLD. The same applies to region-specific phone numbers.

Comment: Where I understand the spec, using only the `email` value, in my case, with live validation, has returned more than a few strings missing the TLD (.com, etc.). So I'm more wondering if theirs an issue when using both in conjunction then the actual spec.

Comment: @darcher that'd be because email addresses with missing TLDs can be valid. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: *"This means that it's down to the browser to validate the email address in this situation."* You may want to clarify this. It's up to the browser's built-in validation *and* the pattern attribute.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the insight (backed by specs)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I also updated the question with a mention of possible side effects when both are used and both are supported. But there isn't anything backing this claim. Figured I'd post it though.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though, in a lot of browsers, the default browser functionality trumps any custom functionality.  I ran into this issue when trying to account for international email addresses (non-alphanumeric languages).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $emails = $('li pre'),
    form = $('form').get(0),
    $input = $('input');

  $emails.each(function() {
    $input.val($(this).text());
    if (form.checkValidity()) {
      $(this).addClass('success').removeClass('fail');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('success').addClass('fail');
    }
  });
  
  $input.val('');
});
```

```css
.success {
  color: green;
}

.fail {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email">Valid</a> Email Addresses:
<ul>
  <li><pre>Abc@example.com</pre></li>
  <li><pre>Abc.123@example.com</pre></li>
  <li><pre>user+mailbox/department=shipping@example.com</pre></li>
  <li><pre>!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`.{|}~@example.com</pre></li>
  <li><pre>"Abc@def"@example.com</pre></li>
  <li><pre>"Fred Bloggs"@example.com</pre></li>
  <li><pre>"Joe.\\Blow"@example.com</pre></li>
  <li><pre>用户@例子.广告</pre></li>
  <li><pre>उपयोगकर्ता@उदाहरण.कॉम</pre></li>
  <li><pre>юзер@екзампл.ком</pre></li>
  <li><pre>θσερ@εχαμπλε.ψομ</pre></li>
  <li><pre>Dörte@Sörensen.example.com</pre></li>
</ul>

<form>
  <input type="email" name="email" pattern=".+@.+" placeholder="XXXX@XXXX" title="XXXX@XXXX" required />
  <button type="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

The browser testing results: https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/0f88466bf4bd5fc4cdec39a7618ed8afc9c82806