# Extract email sub-strings from large document

Tags: python, string

I have a very large .txt file with hundreds of thousands of email addresses scattered throughout.  They all take the format:

```
...<name@domain.com>...
```

What is the best way to have Python to cycle through the entire .txt file looking for a all instances of a certain @domain string, and then grab the entirety of the address within the <...>'s, and add it to a list?  The trouble I have is with the variable length of different addresses.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

This [code](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions) extracts the email addresses in a string. Use it while reading line by line

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "should we use regex more often? let me know at  jdsk@bob.com.lol"
>>> match = re.search(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+', line)
>>> match.group(0)
'jdsk@bob.com.lol'
```

If you have several email addresses use `findall`:

```
>>> line = "should we use regex more often? let me know at  jdsk@bob.com.lol or popop@coco.com"
>>> match = re.findall(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+', line)
>>> match
['jdsk@bob.com.lol', 'popop@coco.com']
```

---

The regex above probably finds the most common non-fake email address. If you want to be completely aligned with the [RFC 5322](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt) you should check which email addresses follow the specification. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) out to avoid any bugs in finding email addresses correctly.

---

**Edit:** as suggested in a comment by [@kostek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1535436/kostek):
In the string `Contact us at support@example.com.` my regex returns support@example.com. (with dot at the end). To avoid this, use `[\w\.,]+@[\w\.,]+\.\w+)`

**Edit II:** another wonderful improvement was mentioned in the comments: `[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w+`which will capture example@do-main.com as well.

**Edit III:** Added further improvements as discussed in the comments: "In addition to allowing + in the beginning of the address, this also ensures that there is at least one period in the domain. It allows multiple segments of domain like abc.co.uk as well, and does NOT match bad@ss :). Finally, you don't actually need to escape periods within a character class, so it doesn't do that."

---

**Update 2023**
Seems [stackabuse](https://stackabuse.com/python-validate-email-address-with-regular-expressions-regex/) has compiled a post based on the popular SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/1031417) mentioned above.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"([-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+(\.[-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+)*|\"([]!#-[^-~ \t]|(\\[\t -~]))+\")@([-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+(\.[-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+)*|\[[\t -Z^-~]*])")

def isValid(email):
    if re.fullmatch(regex, email):
        print("Valid email")
    else:
        print("Invalid email")

isValid("name.surname@gmail.com")
isValid("anonymous123@yahoo.co.uk")
isValid("anonymous123@...uk")
isValid("...@domain.us")
```

---

**Update 2024** (with GPT-4 hints and improvements):

```py
import re

# Compiling the regex pattern for email validation
regex = re.compile(
    r"(?i)"  # Case-insensitive matching
    r"(?:[A-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+"  # Unquoted local part
    r"(?:\.[A-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*"  # Dot-separated atoms in local part
    r"|\"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]"  # Quoted strings
    r"|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*\")"  # Escaped characters in local part
    r"@"  # Separator
    r"[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]*[A-Z0-9])?"  # Domain name
    r"\.(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]*[A-Z0-9])?)+"  # Top-level domain and subdomains
)

def isValid(email):
    """Check if the given email address is valid."""
    return "Valid email" if re.fullmatch(regex, email) else "Invalid email"

# Example Usage
print(isValid("name.surname@gmail.com"))
print(isValid("anonymous123@yahoo.co.uk"))
print(isValid("anonymous123@...uk"))
print(isValid("...@domain.us"))
```

Comment: xyz+44@gmail.com doesn't get caught.

Comment: according to this regex 'bad@ss' is a valid email address ;)

Comment: In string `Contact us at support@example.com.` this regex returns `support@example.com.` (with dot at the end). To avoid this, use `[\w\.,]+@[\w\.,]+\.\w+)`.

Comment: `[\w\.,]+@[\w\.,]+\.\w+` does not match `example@do-main.com` which is a valid email address. So it should be `[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w+`

Comment: @kostek with your regex `Contact us at support@example.com.Or try +33600000000` extracts `support@example.com.Or`

Comment: @J.Doe - That's true, but that's also the expected behavior. `support@example.com.Or` is technically a valid email address, and it's not properly delimited, so it's returning what it's supposed to.

Comment: A `+` should be added to the first character class in the regex because email addresses like `hikingfan+friends@gmail.com` are valid and actually somewhat widely used. The person who owns `hikingfan@gmail.com` can use arbitrary text after `hikingfan+` for various personal purposes.

Comment: Here is my improved regex: `re.compile(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+')`. In addition to allowing `+` in the beginning of the address, this also ensures that there is at least one period in the domain. It allows multiple segments of domain like `abc.co.uk` as well, and does NOT match `bad@ss` :). Finally, you don't actually need to escape periods within a character class, so it doesn't do that. I haven't spent a lot of time thinking about this, but I do believe it's an improvement. It won't be perfect of course.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the following to find all the email addresses in a text and print them in an array or each email on a separate line.

```
import re
line = "why people don't know what regex are? let me know asdfal2@als.com, Users1@gmail.de " \
       "Dariush@dasd-asasdsa.com.lo,Dariush.lastName@someDomain.com"
match = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', line)
for i in match:
    print(i)
```

If you want to add it to a list just print the "match"

```py
# this will print the list
    print(match)
```

Answer (score 11):

```
import re
rgx = r'(?:\.?)([\w\-_+#~!$&\'\.]+(?<!\.)(@|[ ]?\(?[ ]?(at|AT)[ ]?\)?[ ]?)(?<!\.)[\w]+[\w\-\.]*\.[a-zA-Z-]{2,3})(?:[^\w])'
matches = re.findall(rgx, text)
get_first_group = lambda y: list(map(lambda x: x[0], y))
emails = get_first_group(matches)
```

Forgive me lord for having a go at this infamous regex. The regex works for a decent portion of email addresses shown below. I mostly used [this as my basis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049510/1376627) for the valid chars in an email address.

[image]

Feel free to [play around with it here](https://regex101.com/r/Z3DoVr/2)

[I also made a variation](https://regex101.com/r/BVS9y6/9) where the regex captures emails like `name at example.com`

```
(?:\.?)([\w\-_+#~!$&\'\.]+(?<!\.)(@|[ ]\(?[ ]?(at|AT)[ ]?\)?[ ])(?<!\.)[\w]+[\w\-\.]*\.[a-zA-Z-]{2,3})(?:[^\w])
```

Comment: I tried a bunch of regexes on different sites and this is the first one that actually just worked, kudos.

Comment: Unfortunately, this expression can result in catastrophic backtracking: https://regex101.com/r/AwW89g/1

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a specific domain:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "this is an email la@test.com, it will be matched, x@y.com will not, and test@test.com will"
>>> match = re.findall(r'[\w-\._\+%]+@test\.com',text) # replace test\.com with the domain you're looking for, adding a backslash before periods
>>> match
['la@test.com', 'test@test.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

reg_pat = r'\S+@\S+\.\S+'

test_text = 'xyz.byc@cfg-jj.com    ir_er@cu.co.kl   uiufubvcbuw bvkw  ko@com    m@urice'   

emails = re.findall(reg_pat ,test_text,re.IGNORECASE)
print(emails)
```

**Output:**

```
['xyz.byc@cfg-jj.com', 'ir_er@cu.co.kl']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
mess = '''Jawadahmed@gmail.com Ahmed@gmail.com
            abc@gmail'''
email = re.compile(r'([\w\.-]+@gmail.com)')
result= email.findall(mess)

if(result != None):
    print(result)
```

The above code will help to you and bring the Gmail, email only after calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use \b at the end to get the correct email to define ending of the email.

**The regex**

```
[\w\.\-]+@[\w\-\.]+\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Example : string  if mail id has (a-z all lower and _ or any no.0-9), then below will be regex:

```
>>> str1 = "abcdef_12345@gmail.com"
>>> regex1 = "^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$"
>>> re_com = re.compile(regex1)
>>> re_match = re_com.search(str1)
>>> re_match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1063c9ac0>
>>> re_match.group(0)
'abcdef_12345@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
content = ' abcdabcd jcopelan@nyx.cs.du.edu  afgh 65882@mimsy.umd.edu  qwertyuiop mangoe@cs.umd'

match_objects = re.findall(r'\w+@\w+[\.\w+]+', content)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#    \b[\w|\.]+   ---> means begins with any english and number character or dot.

import re

marks = '''

!()[]{};?#$%:'"\,/^&é*

'''

text = 'Hello from priyankv@gmail.com to python@gmail.com, datascience@@gmail.com and machinelearning@@yahoo..com wrong email address: farzad@google.commmm'
# list of sequences of characters:
text_pieces = text.split()
pattern = r'\b[a-zA-Z]{1}[\w|\.]*@[\w|\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$'
for p in text_pieces:
  for x in marks:
    p = p.replace(x, "") 
  if len(re.findall(pattern, p)) > 0:
    print(re.findall(pattern, p))
```

Answer (score 0):

One other way is to divide it into 3 different groups and capture the group(0). See below:

```
emails=[]
for line in email: # email is the text file where some emails exist. 
    e=re.search(r'([.\w\d-]+)(@)([.\w\d-]+)',line) # 3 different groups are composed. 
    if e:
        emails.append(e.group(0))

print(emails)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another approach for this specific problem, with a regex from [emailregex.com](http://emailregex.com/):

```
text = "blabla <hello@world.com>><123@123.at> <huhu@fake> bla bla <myname@some-domain.pt>"

# 1. find all potential email addresses (note: < inside <> is a problem)
matches = re.findall('<\S+?>', text)  # ['<hello@world.com>', '<123@123.at>', '<huhu@fake>', '<myname@somedomain.edu>']

# 2. apply email regex pattern to string inside <>
emails = [ x[1:-1] for x in matches if re.match(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)", x[1:-1]) ]
print emails   # ['hello@world.com', '123@123.at', 'myname@some-domain.pt']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import re 
txt = 'hello from absc@gmail.com to par1@yahoo.com about the meeting @2PM'
email  =re.findall('\S+@\S+',s)
print(email)
```

*Printed output:*

```
['absc@gmail.com', 'par1@yahoo.com']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
with open("file_name",'r') as f:
    s = f.read()
    result = re.findall(r'\S+@\S+',s)
    for r in result:
        print(r)
```

Comment: This code works for getting the email-ids from a file

Comment: ... as well as, for example, `@@@`.`