# How to scrape valid emails from a file using Regex in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a file with some random text including some random emails. I am trying to write a code that can find out emails with valid domains(gmail.com, outlook.com, hotmail.com) using Regex.

Here is the code I've tried so far:

```py
import requests
import re
email_re= r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[^!#$%^&*()]@[gmail|hotmail|outlook]+[.com]+'
with open ('emails.txt') as f:
    read = f.read()
email_data=re.findall(email_re,read)
print(email_data)
```

My **email.txt** file:

```py
sentences in it  pythonprac@dummy.com
test@gmail.com
test1@hotmail.com
The post A rough draft for a 5 paragraph essay and then a final draft. appeared first on EssayBishop.
hello@gm.com
```

*Required Output:*
test@gmail.com,
test1@hotmail.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract email sub-strings from large document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681670/extract-email-sub-strings-from-large-document)

Comment: That really depends a lot on how accurate you want to be, because email addresses can have wildl different formats (all correct, according to specifications), see: https://emailregex.com/

Comment: Maybe read the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) before posting questions; it covers several common beginner mistakes.

Comment: To check if an email is valid (i.e. syntax plus valid domain by checking dns) you can use [pyIsEmail](https://github.com/michaelherold/pyIsEmail).  Answers from how to [Extract email sub-strings from large document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681670/extract-email-sub-strings-from-large-document) shows how to obtain potential email addresses which can then be validated with pyIsEmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regex, this part `[gmail|hotmail|outlook]+` essentially means 'match one or more of any of these characters: `g,m,a,i,l,h,o,t,k,u,|`. What you need is a regex group `(?:...)` like this: `r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[^!#$%^&*()]@(?:gmail|hotmail|outlook)\.com'` And because the `.` in the `.com` means any character followed by `com`, you need to escape it with `\`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
import re
email_re = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', file)
```