# BeautifulSoup and Scraping for emails: unable to pull an email address in text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape websites for emails. I noticed that some emails are not getting picked up... I believe the script I have only picks up emails that are hyperlinked.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

allLinks = [];mails=[]

url = 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/peruggia/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')

def findMails(soup):
    for name in soup.find_all():
        if(name is not None):
            emailText=name.text
            match=bool(re.match('[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$',emailText))
            if('@' in emailText and match==True):
                emailText=emailText.replace(" ",'').replace('\r','')
                emailText=emailText.replace('\n','').replace('\t','')
                if(len(mails)==0)or(emailText not in mails):
                    print(emailText)
                mails.append(emailText)
findMails(soup)
mails=set(mails)
if(len(mails)==0):
    print("NO MAILS FOUND")
```

Target is '`https://sourceforge.net/projects/peruggia/`'. The scan should show `cyberfiles.hacker@gmail.com`. I'm pretty sure I need to edit this line:

```
for name in soup.find_all():
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a different regular expression and this can be a lot simpler.
I found this expression in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17681902).

Also since you are looking for emails anywhere on the site I just used the `findall` function over everything in the body tag.

```py
url = 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/peruggia/'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')


def findMails(soup):
    data = ''
    for tag in soup('body'):
        data += tag.text.strip()

    return re.findall(
        '[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w+', data)


emails = findMails(soup)
print(emails) if len(emails) > 0 else print('Emails Not found')
## Result: ['cyberfiles.hacker@gmail.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
soup.find_all('div', {'class': "review-txt"})
```

That seems to narrow things down, if that's what you're looking for. I only see one email address on that page, in the above `div`. I'm not sure if this will suit your purposes, but it's a start.

Keep in mind that you can normally say `find_all('tag', attrib='something')`, but `class` is a reserved word, so you have to use the dictionary format.

I also notice that your `re.match()` always comes back as False, even when there is an email address in the captured text.