# Extract email from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I have a string as:

```
string="""Recipient:
nolo.lamb@golab.com \--- mail_boundary --- ATTENTION: This email came from an
external source.

Sender: nlrt@vloh.net Subject: [External] *LEGALZOOM OPENS AT $30, IPO
AT $28 Message-Id: <60DC94E60001AE8432F70080_0_2129298@mscv03>
Recipient: Nichole.wen@golab.com \--- mail_boundary --- """
```

All I want to extract the email-ID's corresponding to keyword ***Recipient:*** i.e.
email_id=['nolo.lamb@golab.com','Nichole.wen@golab.com']

What I have tried as:

```
email_id=re.findall(r'Recipient: (.+)',string)
```

Comment: refer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681670/extract-email-sub-strings-from-large-document/17681902

Comment: @gretal Already checked. It gives all the email ID's in string. I want only those which is corresponding to keyword `Recipient:`

Comment: Then just replace the `(.+)` from your pattern with what they give as a valid email pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r'\bRecipient:\s*(\S+@\S+)', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XtiaeZ/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `Recipient:` - a fixed string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\S+@\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars, `@` and one or more non-whitespace chars

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/owtE8M):

```py
import re
text = """Recipient:
nolo.lamb@golab.com \--- mail_boundary --- ATTENTION: This email came from an
external source.
 
Sender: nlrt@vloh.net Subject: [External] *LEGALZOOM OPENS AT $30, IPO
AT $28 Message-Id: <60DC94E60001AE8432F70080_0_2129298@mscv03>
Recipient: Nichole.wen@golab.com \--- mail_boundary --- """
 
print( re.findall(r'\bRecipient:\s*(\S+@\S+)', text) )
# => ['nolo.lamb@golab.com', 'Nichole.wen@golab.com']
```