# Correct EMAIL_REGEX to validate emails using request module Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-re

So I'm kinda new to Web Scraping, but I'm trying to build a program that takes a Google Search Query, find some URL's, and then scrapes emails from this website and put in into an excel file. Everything works fine, except for the email finder:

```
import re
import requests

def scraperFunction(urlInput):
    url=urlInput


    EMAIL_REGEX = r"[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+"
    listOfEmails = []
    r=requests.get(url)
    for re_match in re.findall(EMAIL_REGEX, r.text):
        if re_match not in listOfEmails:
            listOfEmails.append(re_match)
    return listOfEmails
```

This also gives me back some png files or other different files where an `@` was included.

Examples of 'bad'  matches:

- "Certified-Support-Partner-White@2x-2048x612.png"
- swiper@9

I tried to change the `EMAIL_REGEX` value to a value I found somewhere on Stack Overflow, but this made it so that it even removes some good emails. Also, I tried to do `if ".png" not in email` for every value in the list, but this didn't remove them all.

For example, when using `EMAIL_REGEX = r'([A-Za-z0-9]+[.-_])*[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,})+'` it also removes 'normal' emails, like:

- info@domain.com

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

EDIT:
Replacing `EMAIL_REGEX = r"[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+"`  with `EMAIL_REGEX = r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+'` gets rid of the 'swiper@9' example, but it still leaves the PNG file.
Is there a way to exclude certain character combinations using REGEX?

Comment: You could be more specific with the regex. Maybe something like`\b[-\w.]+@[^.]+?[.][a-z]{2,4}\b`. Could you provide examples of bad matches? Have you searched for email regexes already and existing ones didnt meet your requirements? Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/17681902/3783243 ?

Comment: @user3783243 I tried the one in the link you provided and it helped remove some of the bad ones, but it still has the .png ones. I was thinking about using a loop to check if '.png' is in the list, but this is both inefficient and doesn't seem to work all the time.