# email regex not working as expected

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I am using the following regex to validate emails and just noticed some problems and don't see what the issue is :

```
/^[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,6}$/i.test(value)

support@tes is invalid
support@test is valid
support@test.c is invalid
support@test.co is valid
```

the 2,6 is for requiring and ending tld between 2 or 6 and that does not appear to be working either.  I am sure I had this working properly before.

Comment: Why use regex when you can use this => http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

Comment: ...because I also replicate in jquery as needed for validation.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for missing that.  I need to replicate some regexs in jquery as I am using the jquery validation plugin for custom rules. So yes, in this case I am not using php necessarily, but I duplicate the expression in both php and jquery.

Comment: Javascript can always be disabled by a user, therefore I recommend you also use a server-side solution as a backup ;-)

Comment: A valid email address can contain many many more different characters than you're allowing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a regex, `.` is a wildcard (meaning any char).  you need to escape it as `\.`

Keep in mind though, the regex is too restrictive.  You can have non-alpha numeric chars in the address, like `'`

Comment: ahh... never even noticed... seems to do the trick.  Regarding the ' I am marking those as invalid... a-z, A-Z, 0-9, underscore, hyphen, and period.  Plus this handles subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you're not escaping the `.`. There might be more to it than that, but that jumps out at me.

Comment: Yes, the dot should be escaped, but failing to do so opens one to false *positives*, not false negatives.  And the risk of false positives tends to be very low.  This is one error people usually get away with.

Answer (score 0):

This is a decent check for an e-mail with Regex

```
 \w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

However you may want to read this. [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to regex an email address. depending on how precise and restrictive you want it, but to re-write a working regex closest to what you have in you question.  This should work:

```
^[\w_.-]+@[\w]+\.[\w]{2,6}$

support@tes - Invalid
support@test - Invalid
support@test.c - Invalid
support@test.co - Valid
supp34o.rt@tes.com - Valid
```

But also keep in mind ALL the characters allowed in a valid email address - [What characters are allowed in an email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-email-address)