# Ruby Email validation with regex

Tags: ruby, regex, validation, email

I have a large list of emails I am running through.  A lot of the emails have typos. I am trying to build a string that will check valid emails.

this is what I have for regex.

```
def is_a_valid_email?(email)
  (email =~ /^(([A-Za-z0-9]*\.+*_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\+))*[A-Z‌​a-z0-9]+@{1}((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i)
end
```

It passes if an email as underscores and only one period.  I have a lot of emails that have more then one periods in the name itself. How do I check that in regex.

```
hello.me_1@email.com # <~~ valid
foo.bar#gmail.co.uk # <~~~ not valid
f.o.o.b.a.r@gmail.com # <~~~valid 
f...bar@gmail.com # <~~ not valid 
get_at_m.e@gmail  #<~~ valid
```

Can someone help me rewrite my regex ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address?rq=1

Comment: Refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-email-address) for creating your RegEx.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

credit goes to @joshuahunter (below, upvote his answer). Included here so that people see it.

```
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP
```

#### Old TL;DR

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

#### Original answer

You seem to be complicating things a lot, I would simply use:

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

which is taken from [michael hartl's rails book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

since this doesn't meet your dot requirement it can simply be ammended like so:

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([\w+\-]\.?)+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

As mentioned by CAustin, there are many other solutions.

EDIT:

it was pointed out by @installero that the original fails for subdomains with hyphens in them, this version will work (not sure why the character class was missing digits and hyphens in the first place).

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

Comment: How can I add this validation for `email_field`? Currently, it is only checking for presence of `@`. I want that it verifies presence of `.` as well.

Comment: @sshahwhat do you mean by `email_field`? this regex checks that the email is `something_valid@somewhere.tld`, (see the `\.` parts in the second part of the regex.)

Comment: @MikeH-R hmmm, that regex (Michael Hartl's) returns valid for only `@`. Is that a valid email?

Comment: @Mohamad the regex really shouldn't be matching just `@` by itself (though it could be argued as by John Carney below that that would make a more accurate match for an email). all of the groups with `+` require one or more matches. E.g. `[\w+\-.]+` at the start will match `a` or `aaaa` or `a+b.` but not the empty string. See [here for a demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/jJ4gL5/1)

Comment: 'some@email.with-subdomain.com'.match(VALID_EMAIL_REGEX)
 => nil

Comment: @installero , right you are. See edit for version that should work. Interestingly, it would have also failed for `"hello@sub.domain9.com"`.

Comment: The regex validates this, and I'm pretty sure it shouldn't: pre..post@gmail.com This page says it shouldn't, anyway: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax

Huh: https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Comment: @globewalldesk yes, you've got a good point, see the answer by John Carney below. :)

Comment: How about `.dot.@mail.com`? it passed.

Comment: Your regex does not support `foo+bar@example.org` or `foo@domain` which both are valid emails. And I'm not even talking about `"foo@bar.com"@example.org`

Comment: @zmo it does match the first thing you posted and doesn't match the second (and definitely doesn't match the third!).
So a regular expression can't match the _actual_ email RFC (see the answer by @JohnCarney below).

This is a simple regex to match most common domains (explicitly not matching the second example you posted). 

This is the same behaviour as the `URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP` below, which I'll update this answer with (this didn't exist when I wrote this answer.)

Comment: Actually @johnCarney's point is also my point ☺ All one could check with a regex in a mail field is presence of at least one `@`, and illegal patterns (such as `@@` ou `..` in the RHS). You could also enforce a `.` in the RHS excluding local networks mails (or people with mail on a tld which is bad practice).

Comment: this also matches addresses with domain name **starting** with a hyphen: `e@-dom.com`. not so hot.

Answer (score 142):

This has been built into the standard library since at least 2.2.1

```
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP
```

*warning the above considers `a@b` to be a valid email address.

Comment: `'aa@aaa' =~ URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP`

Doesn't work with this case.

Comment: If there is a period, but nothing after it, the regex will return nil. If there is something after the period or no period, it will pass. "This requirement is a willful violation of RFC 5322, which defines a syntax for e-mail addresses that is simultaneously too strict (before the "@" character), too vague (after the "@" character), and too lax (allowing comments, whitespace characters, and quoted strings in manners unfamiliar to most users) to be of practical use here." html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address –

Comment: [a-zA-Z0-9.!\#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)+  (I removed trailing ? and replaced it with +, and then it works as expected)

Comment: Thank you @Benjamin, I needed to know how to implement Josh Hunter's answer and didn't know the right way of comparing the email.

Comment: @JoshuaHunter Yes, the code is correct.
However, since people input too many errors, it seems insufficient to check as that code in the real world.

Answer (score 28):

Here's a great article by [David Celis](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex) explaining why every single regular expression you can find for validating email addresses is wrong, including the ones above posted by Mike.

From the article:

> The local string (the part of the email address that comes before the
>   @) can contain the following characters:
>
> ```
>     `! $ & * - = ` ^ | ~ # % ' + / ? _ { }`
> ```
>
> But guess what? You can use
>   pretty much any character you want if you escape it by surrounding it
>   in quotes. For example, "Look at all these spaces!"@example.com is a
>   valid email address. Nice.

If you need to do a basic check, the best regular expression is simply `/@/`.

Comment: at  a guess ... even though virtually anything can be in an email provided its quoted properly, in reality 99.99% of emails follow a reasonably standard format, and many systems will barf when handed an address they don't recognise as valid (even if it is). If you've got such a component then making sure the email address is *reasonable* as well as valid is important - particularly if it's part of a legacy system or something that can't be changed/updated.

Comment: That's fair, but if you have a space or dollar in your email address, I don't care if you can't use my system.  And I suspect you knew what you were doing when you did it.

Comment: So, "don't even bother trying" is your solution?

Comment: I did not say that. Read my comment and the linked article again.

Answer (score 21):

This one is more short and safe:

```
/\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
```

The regular is used in Devise gem.
But it has some vulnerabilities for these values:

```
  ".....@a....",
  "david.gilbertson@SOME+THING-ODD!!.com",
  "a.b@example,com",
  "a.b@example,co.de"
```

I prefer to use regexp from the ruby library `URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP`

There is a gem for email validations

[Email Validator](https://github.com/balexand/email_validator)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP`! Feels like the best approach since that may be better maintained than dumping a custom regexp somewhere in a codebase.

Comment: `/\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/.match?("r<<r@r.r.com")` returns `true`

Answer (score 15):

Nowadays Ruby provides an email validation regexp in its standard library. You can find it in the `URI::MailTo` module, it's `URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP`.
In Ruby 2.4.1 it evaluates to

```
/\A[a-zA-Z0-9.!\#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*\z/
```

But I'd just use the constant itself.

Comment: This was written 3 years ago and if I recall, I was still using Ruby1.9. Possibly thats the reason why I didn't know about it?  Thank you for your 1 liner though.

Comment: Yeah, but three years later people still answer with their custom regular expressions. Anyway, I did not intend to attack you nor anyone else. I've changed the tone of my answer accordingly.

Comment: THANK YOU. found this only after testing regexps for 1hr.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer suggest using `URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP`.

**However**, this regexp considers `1234@1234` as a valid e-mail address, which is something you probably don't want in a real life app (for instance, AWS SES will throw an exception if you try to send an e-mail to an address like this).

As Darpan points out in the comments, you can simply change the trailing `?` in that regexp with `+`, and it will work as expected. The resulting regex is:

```rb
/\A[a-zA-Z0-9.!\#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)+\z/
```

Since the original `URI::MailTo` regexp, whilst technically valid according to the spec, is imho useless for our needs, we "fix" it in the Devise initializer.

```
# in config/initializers/devise.rb, put this at the beginning of the file
URI::MailTo.send(:remove_const, :EMAIL_REGEXP)
URI::MailTo.const_set(:EMAIL_REGEXP, /\A[a-zA-Z0-9.!\#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)+\z/)

# And then find `config.email_regexp` (it will already be there in the file) and change it to:
config.email_regexp = URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP
```

If you're wondering why this monkeypatch isn't put in a separate initializer file, you'd have to name the initializer file as `00_xxx.rb` to make it load before the devise initializer. This is against Rails docs recommendations, which actually [suggests](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files) you use a single initializer for cases like this:

> If an initializer has code that relies on code in another initializer, you can combine them into a single initializer instead. This makes the dependencies more explicit, and can help surface new concepts within your application. Rails also supports numbering of initializer file names, but this can lead to file name churn.

Comment: This is the best answer. I simplified things further by setting the Devise email_regexp to the updated regex directly: `config.email_regexp = /\A[a-zA-Z0-9.!\#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)+\z/`

Comment: Also I have now stumbled upon the email `"info@кириллическийдомен.рф"` that is probably valid but isn't matched by this constant.

Answer (score 6):

### TL;DR

Any custom regexp you'll find on internet, including `URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP`, is wrong.

Here what you should use:

```rb
# The closest thing to RFC_5322
RFC_5322 = /\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_‘{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_‘{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])\z/i

# Lighter more practical version RFC_5322 that will be more useful in real life
RFC_5322_light = /\A[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_‘{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_‘{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\z/i

# Same as the light version but with length limit enforcing
RFC_5322_with_length = /\A(?=[a-z0-9@.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_‘{|}~-]{6,254}\z)(?=[a-z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_‘{|}~-]{1,64}@)[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_‘{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_‘{|}~-]+)*@(?:(?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\z)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\z/i
```

### Details

The last RFC defining email address format is [RFC5322 - Internet Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322).

You can check the section [3.4.1.  Addr-Spec Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1). If we only look at the first part, the `@` split the local part (on the left) and the domain (on the right).

> addr-spec       =   local-part "@" domain
>
> local-part      =   dot-atom / quoted-string / obs-local-part

For example, the local part, can contain a *dot-atom* or a *quoted-string* defined here:

- [3.2.3.  Atom](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.3)
- [3.2.4.  Quoted Strings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.4)

It's a bit complex but your email address can contain many ASCII special character that are excluded of many regexp (like `#`, `$`, `&`, etc.).

On the other hand, `URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP` is defined in [`ruby/lib/uri/mailto.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/a7d467a792c644a7260d6560ea2002fdb8ff6de3/lib/uri/mailto.rb#L55) with the following regexp:

```rb
EMAIL_REGEXP = /\A[a-zA-Z0-9.!\#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*\z/
```

The comment above this regexp suggest they followed the recommendations at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address.

> A valid email address is a string that matches the email production of the following ABNF, the character set for which is Unicode. This ABNF implements the extensions described in RFC 1123. [ABNF] [RFC5322] [RFC1034] [RFC1123]

But WHATWG spec add the following comment, which is very important:

> This requirement is a willful violation of RFC 5322, which defines a syntax for email addresses that is simultaneously too strict (before the "@" character), too vague (after the "@" character), and too lax (allowing comments, whitespace characters, and quoted strings in manners unfamiliar to most users) to be of practical use here.

So WHATWG is telling us they didn't respect the RFC that was standardizing the email address format. They say the domain part is too vague in RFC 5322 but RFC 5322 gives this note to tell use we have to check other RFCs for a more complete domain format spec:

> Note: A liberal syntax for the domain portion of addr-spec is
> given here.  However, the domain portion contains addressing
> information specified by and used in other protocols (e.g.,
> [RFC1034], [RFC1035], [RFC1123], [RFC5321]).  It is therefore
> incumbent upon implementations to conform to the syntax of
> addresses for the context in which they are used.

WHATWG also tells us that the local-part in RFC 5322 is too strict. But look at `URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP` that follows WHATWG spec instead:

```rb
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('.@toto.fr') # => true
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('-@z') # => true
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('++++++++.........@z') # => true
```

In the contrary WHATWG spec (and so `URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP`) is way too lax.

So I found at https://emailregex.com/ a *General Email Regex (RFC 5322 Official Standard)* (see [summary](https://emailregex.com/email-validation-summary/)).

The explanation and alternatives can be found at https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html.

```
# Blind RFC 5322
\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])\z

# RFC 5322, practical version (omit IP addresses, domain-specific addresses, the syntax using double quotes and square brackets)
\A[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\z

# RFC 5322, practical version (similar as previous + length limits enfocing)
\A(?=[a-z0-9@.!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{|}~-]{6,254}\z)(?=[a-z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{|}~-]{1,64}@)[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{|}~-]+)*@(?:(?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\z)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\z
```

And as you can see on the screenshot below none of addresses accepted by WHATWG / `URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP` is valid.

[image: invalid email addresses]

Let's do the same thing locally:

```rb
RFC_5322 = /\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])\z/i
```

Now we can compare both (on Ruby 3.2.0):

```rb
# WHATWG
## Invalid cases
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('.@toto.fr') # => true
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('-@z') # => true
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('++++++++.........@z') # => true
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('invalíd@mail.com') # => false
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('invalid%$£"@domain.com') # => false
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('invalid£@domain.com') # => false
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('invali"d@domain.com') # => false
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('.dot..dot.@example.org') # => true
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('!#$%’*+-/=?^_`{|}~@example.org') # => false
## Valid cases
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('sometest@gmail.com') # => true
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('some+test@gmail.com') # => true
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('stuart.sillitoe@prodirectsport.net') # => true
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('_valid@mail.com') # => true
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('valid%$@domain.com') # => true
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP.match?('"valid"@domain.com') # crash with error NameError

# RFC 5322
## Invalid cases
RFC_5322.match?('.@toto.fr') # => false
RFC_5322.match?('-@z') # => false
RFC_5322.match?('++++++++.........@z') # => false
RFC_5322.match?('invalíd@mail.com') # => false
RFC_5322.match?('invalid%$£"@domain.com') # => false
RFC_5322.match?('invalid£@domain.com') # => false
RFC_5322.match?('invali"d@domain.com') # => false
RFC_5322.match?('.dot..dot.@example.org') # => false
RFC_5322.match?('!#$%’*+-/=?^_`{|}~@example.org') # => false
## Valid cases
RFC_5322.match?('sometest@gmail.com') # => true
RFC_5322.match?('some+test@gmail.com') # => true
RFC_5322.match?('stuart.sillitoe@prodirectsport.net') # => true
RFC_5322.match?('_valid@mail.com') # => true
RFC_5322.match?('valid%$@domain.com') # => true
RFC_5322.match?('"valid"@domain.com') # => true

# RFC 5322 light (same results with RFC_5322_with_length)
## Invalid cases
RFC_5322_light.match?('.@toto.fr') # => false
RFC_5322_light.match?('-@z') # => false
RFC_5322_light.match?('++++++++.........@z') # => false
RFC_5322_light.match?('invalíd@mail.com') # => false
RFC_5322_light.match?('invalid%$£"@domain.com') # => false
RFC_5322_light.match?('invalid£@domain.com') # => false
RFC_5322_light.match?('invali"d@domain.com') # => false
RFC_5322_light.match?('.dot..dot.@example.org') # => false
RFC_5322_light.match?('!#$%’*+-/=?^_`{|}~@example.org') # => false
## Valid cases
RFC_5322_light.match?('sometest@gmail.com') # => true
RFC_5322_light.match?('some+test@gmail.com') # => true
RFC_5322_light.match?('stuart.sillitoe@prodirectsport.net') # => true
RFC_5322_light.match?('_valid@mail.com') # => true
RFC_5322_light.match?('valid%$@domain.com') # => true
RFC_5322_light.match?('"valid"@domain.com') # => false (difference with "pure" version)
```

Warning this test is no complete and does not cover all cases.

Answer (score 5):

I guess the example from the book can be improved to match emails with `-` in subdomain.

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

For example:

```
> 'some@email.with-subdomain.com' =~ VALID_EMAIL_REGEX
=> 0
```

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't see your answer until now, this was what I added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yours is complicated indeed.

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

The above code should suffice.

Explanation of each piece of the expression above for clarification:

Start of regex:

```
/
```

Match the start of a string:

```
\A
```

At least one word character, plus, hyphen, or dot:

```
[\w+\-.]+
```

A literal "at sign":

```
@
```

A literal dot:

```
\.
```

At least one letter:

```
[a-z]+
```

Match the end of a string:

```
\z
```

End of regex:

```
/
```

Case insensitive:

```
i
```

Putting it back together again:

```
/\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

Check out [Rubular](http://rubular.com) to conveniently test your expressions as you write them.

Comment: Nice one, but non-latin characters should be prohibited. For example, protonmail doesn't let me create this email: "helloworld\u20131234@protonmail.com" (helloworld–1234@protonmail.com). But your regexp validates this as a good email.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Devise, you can also use their included regex via:

```
Devise.email_regexp
```

which returns:

```
/\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
/\A[a-zA-Z0-9.!\#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)+\z/
```

Explanation below.

Whilst Joshua Hunter's answer is great URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP has a significant flaw in my opinion.

It matches `fred@example` which cause `Net::SMTPSyntaxError: 501 5.1.3 Bad recipient address syntax` errors.

URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP evaluates to

```
/\A[a-zA-Z0-9.!\#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*\z/
```

Changing the last star to a plus makes it better.

Note: this is pointed out in Darpan's comment to Joshua Hunter's answer, but I think it deserves its own answer to make it more visible.

Answer (score 1):

Stop validating emails with regex. Instead send an email with some secret token.

Ultimately if you **really** need to validate, use [HTML5 email](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#basic_validation) validation. Example running on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/library/7tKZSs).

Or use the most minimalistic regex

```
/@/
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby Multiple Emails validation with regex in the controller

```
emails = testcontroller@gmail.com,testregex@gmail.com,etc...
unless emails =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
   flash[:error] = "Invalid emails"
else
   Here send invitation and create users
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a valid email id we use a regular expression

```
/\A[a-zA-Z0-9.!\#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*\z/
```

Answer (score -1):

This works good for me:

```
if email.match?('[a-z0-9]+[_a-z0-9\.-]*[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})')
      puts 'matches!'
else
      puts 'it doesn\'t match!'
end
```

Answer (score -1):

try this!!!

[`/\[A-Z0-9._%+-\]+@\[A-Z0-9.-\]+\.\[AZ\]{2,4}/i`](http://www.rubular.com/r/VxMlGlWcLW)

only email string selected

```
"Robert Donhan" <bob@email.com>sadfadf
Robert Donhan <bob@email.com>
"Robert Donhan" abc.bob@email.comasdfadf
Robert Donhan bob@email.comadfd
```

Comment: The main concern with this regex would be inability to parse long top-level domains such as `.amsterdam` and many many more recently added ones.