# how to validate email using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-5, email-validation

i want to validate email but i couldn't. is there method to validate? 
param[0] is email.
if param[0] =~ Devise.email_regexp is not work.

```
if param[0] =~ Devise.email_regexp
  {email: param[0], reason: I18n.t("user.error.invalid_email")}
```

Comment: Check out this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993545/ruby-email-validation-with-regex

Comment: You know that `devise`s built in email validation is extraordinarily simple. e.g. `/\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/` *"Email regex used to validate email formats. It simply asserts that one (and only one) @ exists in the given string. This is mainly to give user feedback and not to assert the e-mail validity."* straight from the config file

Comment: @engineersmnky what’s wrong with spaces? They are perfectly allowed in RFC. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression

Comment: shouldn't you use `unless`? because if the condition in the if is `true`, `param[0]` is email. And you are returning an error in this case.