# Why is validation being skipped?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an email `ActiveRecord` (sub-class, different PG DB) with the following validation:

```rb
class Email < DbRecord
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessor :skip_validation
  alias_method :skip_validation?, :skip_validation

  validates :value,
            presence: true,
            uniqueness: true,
            format: {
              with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP,
              message: "is an invalid email address",
              allow_blank: true,
            },
            unless: :skip_validation?

  before_validation { |record| record.value = record.value&.downcase }
```

`skip_validation` is nil. There are no other instance methods.

When there's no `user_id` the validation works as expected.

```
> e = Email.new(value: "foo@bar")
=> #<Email id: nil, user_id: nil, value: "foo@bar">

> e.valid?
=> false
```

When there's a `user_id` the bogus email doesn't trigger the validation.

```
> e = Email.new(user_id: 7, value: "foo@bar")
=> #<Email id: nil, user_id: 7, value: "foo@bar">

> e.valid?
=> true
```

Note that setting `validate: true` on `belongs_to` doesn't help:

```rb
class Email < DbRecord
  belongs_to :user, validate: true
```

Still presents:

```
> e = Email.new(user_id: 7, value: "foo@bar")
=> #<Email id: nil, user_id: 7, value: "foo@bar">

> e.valid?
=> true
```

Why is that? What else should I be looking at/for?

Answer (score 1):

Two-step answer:

1. `"foo@bar"` is a valid email according to `URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP`...

I can't even, but [others have hit the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49925519/438992) so...

As I always tell everyone else: check your assumptions. I *assumed* the validation was failing because of the email address, and in my sleep-deprived state I didn't verify the errors.

So why was it failing validation?

2. Rails 5 changed `belongs_to` to make the related ID mandatory, so in order for this to make sense (in my use-case) I also needed to add:

```rb
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

to get the expected error messages back during validation.