# How do I check if a user input contains a period (.) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to check that 3 condiditons are met when asking a user for an email. The user must input something, they must include the @ symbol, and include a domain (.com, .edu, .net, etc). For the domian I am mainly checking for a period.  how do i make sure the user input meets these 3 conditions?

Here is the code I use:

```
    def email()
        print "What is the students email? "
        email = gets.chomp

        if email.empty? && email.include?("@") && email.include?(".")
            puts "working"
        else
            puts "Please enter a valid email. "
            email()
        end 
    end

    email()
```

Here is an example of me running the method in terminal:

[image: Terminal output]

I am using Ruby and VScode.

Comment: According to your code, email must be empty _and_ contain an @ and a dot. This cannot happen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby Email validation with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993545/ruby-email-validation-with-regex)

Comment: Another way: `(i = str.index('@')) && str.index('.', i+2)`. See [String#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-index).

Comment: A small modification of your code here:  
 "  if ((!email.empty? && email.include?("@")) && (email.include?("."))) "
this is not much useful as regex, but definitely a easy way for the new users in ruby

Comment: See [here](https://rubygarage.org/blog/how-to-validate-emails) for a regex for domain names.

Comment: _"The user must input something"_ – in this case `email.empty?` should probably be `!email.empty?`, i.e. be _not_ empty. However, that emptiness check is superfluous because `include?('@')` / `include?('.')` can only become `true` if the email isn't empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple regexp like this

```
email.match?(/\A.+@.+\..+\z/)
```

```
/
  \A  # string begin
  .+  # minimum 1 character
  @   # @
  .+  # minimum 1 character
  \.  # dot
  .+  # minimum 1 character
  \z  # string end
/x
```

Comment: Considering that the OP has not asked for a comprehensive test of the required format I believe `/@.+\./` would suffice.