# Characters that are not supported inside Email Address

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a task in which we want to combine email address into a single string which is separated by  special characters. Please suggest me what character I use

Comment: Outlook Allow pipe | inside email Address

Comment: Choose the one suits your requirement from here -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Invalid_email_addresses

Comment: How about using multiple characters? I suggest "`76266804-ff1d-4235-8c12-d8e15cde7dcf`".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `|` which is common used as separator

```
List<string> emails = new List<string>();

emails.Add("one@example.com");
emails.Add("two@example.com");

string emailString  = "";
foreach(var email in emails){
  emailString += email + "|";
}

emailString = emailString.TrimEnd('|');
```

**Edit:** According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8907897/492258)
use back slash but don't forget it to escape such as double or triple backslash

Comment: Thanks for you answer but outlook allow pipe charters inside email address. Actually I need two charter. I pick one is space . Please suggest another

Comment: @AdityaPotdar How about back slash, please see Edit