# Is it possible to use double @ in an email address?

Tags: security, email, sendmail

I know Yahoo and Gmail do not accept it. But I want to know if it's possible for a person to create an email address with double `@` in address and if they can receive emails with that address?

For example: `info@stackoverflow.com@example.com`.

I do not want to use this non standard format, but I want to know if a hacker can do it?

Comment: Lookup "email address" on wikipedia - it will point you at the right standards etc to get the definitive answer.

Comment: I've given a comment lower but older people will remember having to nest Banyan vines email for gateways (Digital famously used Banyan Vines).  It has to be in the local-part and it has to be quoted. "foo@example"@example.com is valid. Many servers filter anything that looks like it is wrapped in this way, sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-email-address) question's answer says:

> The local-part of the e-mail address may use any of these ASCII characters:
>
> - Uppercase and lowercase English letters (a-z, A-Z)
> - Digits 0 to 9
> - Characters ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^ _ ` { | }
> - Character . (dot, period, full stop) provided that it is not the first or last
>   character, and provided also that it does not appear two or more times
>   consecutively.

so it is *usually* not allowed :)

Answer (score 4):

According to the wiki, it is allowed.

Space and special characters "(),:;<>@[\] are allowed with restrictions (they are only allowed inside a quoted string, as described in the paragraph below, and in addition, a backslash or double-quote must be preceded by a backslash).

Answer (score 3):

No it is not allowed. See the [RFC Section 3.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1)

> An addr-spec is a specific Internet identifier that contains a
> locally interpreted string followed by the at-sign character ("@",
> ASCII value 64) followed by an Internet domain.  The locally
> interpreted string is either a quoted-string or a dot-atom.  If the
> string can be represented as a dot-atom (that is, it contains no
> characters other than atext characters or "." surrounded by atext
> characters), then the dot-atom form SHOULD be used and the quoted-
> string form SHOULD NOT be used.  Comments and folding white space
> SHOULD NOT be used around the "@" in the addr-spec.

Comment: It has to be quoted.  "foo@@bar"@example.com is a valid email. Read further.