# How to check a name it is starts with a numeric values and extract that number in php?

Tags: php

In my program I have a account ID and I want to create a username. It is cannot contain numeric values at the start of their name unless those numeric numbers are equal to their account ID number. For example if I am seller ID 44 and I try to create username “37verifier” it is not fine. But if I try to create 44Verifier then it is fine. If I try to create “A37verifier”, again this is fine. And also allowed only "@ and .(dot)" special character in name (if it is email id format), not allowed other special characters in my username.

How can I do it in a php script? Please help me.

Comment: Try to find more info for 'Regular expressions in PHP'

Comment: An emailaddress allows more special characters than `@` and `.` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-email-address

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions and check if the username checks it.

Assuming we already have two variables, `$username` is the string to check and `$ID` is the user ID.

```
$regexp="/^(".$ID."|[a-z@\.]+)[a-z0-9@\.]+$/i";
if (preg_match($regexp,$username))
{
    //... do something
}else{
    die("Invalid username");
}
```

This will match if:

- The user name starts with the user ID
- The user name starts with a letter, dot or @ character

This will not match if the user nae starts with a number different than the user ID.

However, this wont check if the provided `username`is a valid email address.