# Identify duplicate email with . inside it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

How to identify duplicate emails in table with . inside in ruby on rails

E.x . `user 1: testaccount@gmail.com,`

```
  user 2: test.account@gmail.com,

  user 3: tes.t.account@gmail.com,

  user 4: test.a.ccount@gmail.com
```

Gmail refers to same email account for each emails included by '.'  .  Gmail ignores dots in email username

Comment: Normalise the field `before_validation` by stripping the dots from the left side in a unique column?

Comment: An email with a dot does not indicate it will be a duplicate. Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-email-address

Comment: @JoshBrody: it is creating malicious accounts in any other site.

Comment: I don't think an email address is going to stop someone from being malicious.

Comment: @JoshBrody gmail ignores dots in email username

Comment: Why don't you just make them verify their email address by emailing them a link to click. Then add a cleanup job that deletes any unverified accounts after 7 days or something.

Answer (score 1):

in postgesql:

```
select distinct a from (select replace(adr,'.','') as a from t) t2;
```

gives you unique set

```
select a,count(*) from (select replace(adr,'.','') as a from t) t2 group by a;
```

gives you how many times each value has been met

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e893a2/3

Answer (score 0):

To-the-dot duplicated email records can be identified directly in your SQL statement or in your ruby app code.

Here's a simple query to return all normalized email and the number of users associated with each normalized email:

```
User.group("replace(email,'.','')").count
```

which is translated to the following SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, replace(email,'.','') AS replace_email FROM "users" GROUP BY replace(email,'.','')
```

and returns something like the following hash:

```
{"x@gmailcom"=>1, "da@gmailcom"=>2}
```

Indicating there are 2 users with normalized email equals to `da@gmailcom`.

Alternitevly you can use [group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) in ruby code:

```
User.all.group_by{ |u| u.email.gsub('.','') }
```