# Add Dash to Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to modify an existing Regex expression being pulled in from a properties file from a Java program that someone else built.

The current Regex expression used to match an email address is -

```
RR.emailRegex=^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

That matches email addresses such as **abc.xyz@example.com**, but now some email addresses have dashes in them such as **abc-def.xyz@example.com** and those are failing the Regex pattern match.

What would my new Regex expression be to add the dash to that regular expression match or is there a better way to represent that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basing on the regex you are using, you can add the dash into your character class:

```
RR.emailRegex=^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
add
RR.emailRegex=^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$
```

Btw, you can shorten your regex like this:

```
RR.emailRegex=^[\\w.-]+@[\\w-]+\\.[\\w-]+$
```

Anyway, I would use [Apache EmailValidator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html) instead like this:

```
if (EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid(email)) ....
```

Answer (score 6):

Meaning of `-` inside a character class is different than used elsewhere. Inside character class `-` denotes range. e.g. `0-9`. If you want to include `-`, write it in beginning or ending of character class like `[-0-9]` or `[0-9-]`.

You also don't need to escape `.` inside character class because it is treated as `.` literally inside character class.

Your regex can be simplified further. `\w` denotes `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. So you can use

```
^[-\w.]+@[\w]+\.[\w]+$
```

In *Java*, this can be written as

```
^[-\\w.]+@[\\w]+\\.[\\w]+$
```

Answer (score 2):

`^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.\\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$`

Should solve your problem. In regex you need to escape anything that has meaning in the Regex engine (eg. -, ?, *, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The correct Regex fix is below.

**OLD Regex Expression**

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

**NEW Regex Expression**

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$
```

Comment: don't you need to escape the dash when its between square brackets?

Comment: I am not 100% sure as Regex is a bit tough for me to understand, but making the change above worked and accepted **abc-def.xyz@example.com** as a valid email address in my program.

Comment: That would be because he's accepting any character at all via the unescaped `.` character. This is functionally the same as `.*@.*\\..*`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address)  it covers all special cases, so the best one that's work correctly with java is

```
    String pattern ="(?:[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";
```