# Regular Expression to find Email in a Text

Tags: php, regex, linux

I am using PHP to find e-mail address in a given text. 
My current regex is:

```
'/([\w+\.]*\w+@[\w+\.]*\w+[\w+\-\w+]*\.\w+)/is'
```

It is consuming a lot of CPU resources. Is there any  optimized and low resource utilized ( i.e CPU ) RegEx for finding a Valid E-mails in a given text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: use the regex mentioned by @RAnders00 or you need to use atomic groups or possessive quantifiers,otherwise there will be too much of backtracking __(your regex is incorrect though)__

Comment: Thanks @RAnders00 for pointing that link..

Answer (score 1):

This

```
/^[^@]+@[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)+$/
```

is better than yours.

## Why?

Let's say we want to test this email: `foo@bar.co.uk`

In case of success my regexp perform **14 steps** to find the solution.
Yours in **22 steps**.

## BUT THE BIGGEST DIFFERENCE IS IN NON-MATCHING CASE

Let's say we want to test this email: `foo@bar.co.uk.foo.`

My regex performs **31 steps** and fails

Yours (that should be modified with `^` and `$` delimiters, otherwise it will match this as a good one) performs **292 steps** and fails!

Comment: What application you are using to check your regex? Can you tell me, so i can also check where I am making mistake.

Comment: @Siddharthsharma: use regex101.com

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes trading off some false positives for better performance is desirable:

```
/[^ @]*@[^ ]*/
```

This should be quite fast. It will also match stuff like `__imp__MessageBoxW@16`, but such constructs aren't that common in normal text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/[-\d\w\W]+@[-\d\w.+_]+.\w{2,4}/
```

Matches:

`hello.world@example.com`
`my_guru@lcoalhost`
`guy.31@site.co`, etc...

Tested at http://regexr.com/

Comment: e-mail contains symbols also. This regex will not check for that.

Comment: but not these Characters  ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^ _ ` { | } ~

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-email-address

Comment: Sorry for that. You edited your regex. Now it's working. Thanks

Comment: `[-\d\w\W]` (equal to `[\w\W]`) matches all characters there are in the world. Unescaped `.` matches any character but a newline. Also, testing a regex that should work in PCRE in a JavaScript compatible regex tester is not the best idea.