# Regex including date string, email, number

Tags: java, regex

I have this regex expression:

```
String patt = "(\\w+?)(:|<|>)(\\w+?),"; 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patt);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(search + ",");
```

I am able to match a string like

```
search = "firstName:Giorgio"
```

But I'm not able to match string like

```
search = "email:giorgio.rossi@libero.it"
```

or

```
search = "dataregistrazione:27/10/2016"
```

How I should modify the regex expression in order to match these strings?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
String pat = "(\\w+)[:<>]([^,]+)"; // Add a , at the end if it is necessary
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RALH2w/1)

**Details**:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more word chars
- `[:<>]` - one of the chars inside the character class, `:`, `<`, or `>`
- `([^,]+)`   - Group 2 capturing 1 or more chars other than `,` (in the demo, I added `\n` as the demo input text contains newlines).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = new String[]{"firstName:Giorgio", "email:giorgio.rossi@libero.it", "dataregistrazione:27/10/2016"};
    String pattern = "(\\w+[:|<|>]\\w+)|(\\w+:\\w+\\.\\w+@\\w+\\.\\w+)|(\\w+:\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})";
    for(String str : arr){
        if(str.matches(pattern))
            System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

output is:

```
firstName:Giorgio
email:giorgio.rossi@libero.it
dataregistrazione:27/10/2016
```

But you have to remember that this regex will work only for your format of data.
 To make up the universal regex you should use [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) documents and articles (i.e [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part)) about email format. 
Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-email-address) question can be useful.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Character class `\w` matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. So kindly change the regex as `(\\w+?)(:|<|>)(.*),` to match any character from `:` to `,`.

Or mention all characters that you can expect i.e. `(\\w+?)(:|<|>)[@.\\w\\/]*,` .