# Safe delimiter for dsv of email addresses

Tags: email, mime, email-validation, email-address

I need to use/store a delimiter separated value string (not csv) of email addresses. I need to choose a delimiter that is safe.

E.g. `bar@foo.com,baz@foo.com,` - comma in this e.g. is unsafe as it's valid within an email address.

It seems that almost anything [is allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049510/7059613) in an email address, especially now with [internationalized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2071250/7059613) email addresses.

What is a safe delimiter to use without jumping through hoops because of corner cases? I can't find a character in [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) which which is expressly invalid (but there are lots of email related related RFCs, so I'm not sure which to consult).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally used `\` because that is an escape character, however it is allowed if escaped. @MatWalker's answer recommends stuff like CR or LF etc, but those are allowed too, if they are escaped.

Escaping and replacing and unescaping got a bit complicated. So right now I'm using control character `STX` (i.e. "Start of Text", decimal 2).

Although the RFC doesn't mention (from what I've seen) whether control charactes are valid/invalid, there doesn't seem to be anything that makes it a bad choice. It does say that control chars are "discouraged", but not prohibited for header fields.

Answer (score 1):

Where/how will you be storing the string and what will the delimiter be used for?

You could use a non-visible ascii character such as the CR (Ascii 13) or Tab (Ascii 9).

Comment: Storing in a database. How did you arrive at those chars? [The spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.5) mentions that ascii control chars are "discouraged" for the body, but does not say anything about the headers, So I assume that those are technically allowed in an email address? Doesn't make sense, admittedly, but we need to rely on the formal spec.