# How to customize ASP.NET Identity Core Username to allow special characters and space

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity

I have changed my **Register Action** Method to accept user Name instead of Email.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser 
    {
        UserName = model.Name,
        Email = model.Email,
    };
```

But when I Enter Name in TextBox like **Joe Smith** It give me an error that is **Invalid UserName**. It is not allowing user Name to Accept White space. My Question is how can I modify the builtin User Name to allow space and special characters. I am using ASP.NET Core.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 12):

So cloudikka's answer had it right. I'll just add explicitly (cloudikka's link explained it as well) that you need to list ALL the characters you want to allow (not just the whitespace or special characters), like this:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+/ ";
});
```

and NOT this `options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = " ";` which means 'only whitespace characters allowed'. (I reckon this was Babar's problem.)

Comment: this should be marked as answer. it works for me. the AllowedUserNameCharacters  should be set with ALL characters we want to allow.

Answer (score 11):

You can set user validation rules configuring identity with options in your Startup.cs.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "allowed characters here";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true/false;
});
```

Related resources:

[Configure Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Comment: It is not allowing white space and special characters

Comment: I am reviewing the ASP.NET Identity source code and see nothing that will ban whitespace from usage, if you specify one in the AllowedUserNameCharacters property.

Comment: I always get that error 'Invalid UserName' either I use space or not. Code is not even working with plain character.

Comment: Without the code it will be hard to find out for anyone.

Answer (score 6):

The proposed solution can be tricky if you have an exhaustive list of special characters to whitelist.

If you want to blacklist instead, disable the whitelist in startup.cs:

```
 services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(
                options =>
                {                        
                    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = string.Empty;
                })
```

Then create your custom user validator

```
 public class UsernameValidator<TUser> : IUserValidator<TUser>
where TUser : User
{
    public Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
    {                
        if (user.UserName.Any(x=>x ==':' || x == ';' || x == ' ' || x == ','))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError
            {
                Code = "InvalidCharactersUsername",
                Description = "Username can not contain ':', ';', ' ' or ','"
            }));
        }
        return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
    }        
}
```

Then add it to startup.cs:

```
 services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(
                options =>
                {
                    options.Password = new PasswordOptions
                    {
                        RequiredLength = 8,
                        RequireUppercase = true,
                        RequireNonAlphanumeric = true,
                        RequireDigit = true,
                        RequireLowercase = true
                    };
                    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = string.Empty;
                }).AddUserValidator<UsernameValidator<User>>()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => { options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = String.Empty; options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: I found that I needed to support a wide variety of characters as they already existed in customer installs so this worked best for me - It disables the checking on user names.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the problems caused by the en-US default mindset of most application developers..

I generated a small class that does this for me like so...

```
options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =Utilities.GetAllWritableCharacters(encoding: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

the helper class contains the GetAllWritableCharacters method like so

```
public class Utilities
{
    public static string GetAllWritableCharacters(Encoding encoding)
    {
        encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding.WebName, new EncoderExceptionFallback(), new DecoderExceptionFallback());
        var sb= new StringBuilder();
         
        char[] chars = new char[1];
        byte[] bytes = new byte[16];

           
        for (int i = 20; i <=  char.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            chars[0] = (char)i;
            try
            {
                int count = encoding.GetBytes(chars, 0, 1, bytes, 0);

                if (count != 0)
                {
                    sb.Append(chars[0]);
                }
            }
            catch 
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

now you can accept all meaningful characters from a character set including spaces and "exotic" letters

Answer (score 1):

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(opts =>
        {

            opts.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            opts.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
            "abcçdefgğhijklmnoöpqrsştuüvwxyzABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPQRSŞTUÜVWXYZ0123456789-._";
            opts.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            opts.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        }).AddPasswordValidator<CustomPasswordValidator>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>();
```

> You can basically enter any character you want between two quotes.
> options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = " ";

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Username is same as Email.  Email allows special characters such as "+" and "/".  So, special characters in Username is expected.

Special characters in Email Address discussed here:
[What characters are allowed in an email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address)

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned by @Jaffal the UserName should not allow special characters or white spaces. It should be considered as a unique user identifier (a.k.a. nickname or email). 
To get nicely displayed user name you might want to introduce a new property.

E.g. add a new property called `Name` or in some other implementation may be two fields `GivenName` and `FamilyName`. And ask user to fill in her name to these fields.

To extend the database with the extra field(s) your migration can be:

```
public partial class ApplicationUserNamePropertyAdded : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "Name",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            nullable: true);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "Name",
            table: "AspNetUsers");
    }
}
```

In your code when you Register a new user using ASP.NET Identity classes you will have a code line like:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Name = model.Name };
```

Basically, the user's `UserName` will always be the same as Email and another `Name` property will be used for displaying purposes.

Answer (score -3):

UserName should not allow special characters or white spaces, I don't think that there is any website will allow you to do that, you can use FirstName and Last name to get an info like "Joe Smith".

Comment: I just want to store full Name First Name + Last Name in table and It has to a space between them.

Comment: Then as I told you keep username as is and use a new property FullName in ApplicationUser class

Comment: Ok How can I allow duplicate username? Is this possible?

Comment: @Jaffal: Whitesoace is bad practice because username is handle and it is used in the address bar and Joe%20Smith is ugly. Special characters can make web page behave strange(? querystring, # fragment). That is why we are not using special characters in general. Also special characters are not exactly human friendly and readable. Except _ or -.

Comment: @Babar It is not good idea to have duplicity in usernames. Username is handle and have to be unique.

Comment: @cloudikka that's why I told Babar to keep username as is and use new property call it FullName for the purpose he wants and username will stay as is unique doesn't accept special characters or whitespaces

Babar just create new property inside ApplicationUser

Comment: @Jaffal: I just extend your comment! I didnt meant to disagree with you.