# UserName has invalid characters - only digits and characters are allowed

Tags: asp.net-identity

I'm trying to set the allowed characters in asp .net core identity.  I have the following setting in my startup.cs file:

options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-@._+";

I'm trying to set my user name to the supplied email address.  In debugging, my email address is coming through properly.  Any insight into what I should set on this?

[I've been through this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988003/how-to-customize-asp-net-identity-core-username-to-allow-special-characters-and).

Comment: Your question doesn't state what the problem is. You indicate it is coming through properly, so what is the issue?

Comment: Apologies on not being specific enough.  :-)  The error message is coming back when I attempt to call the UserManager's CreateAsync Method.  I've tried various versions of passing an AspNetUser object with various properties.  The error happens no matter what properties I fill in.  
var user = new AspNetUser() { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
                UserName = UserName, NormalizedUserName = UserName.ToUpper(), 
                NormalizedEmail = UserName.ToUpper(), Email = UserName };

            var userCreate = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);