# Regex validator for email address with exactly 10 numbers before @

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out the JavaScript regex validator that checks first whether the string appears to be a valid email address and second whether there are 10 and only 10 numbers before the `@` sign. I have come up with this:

```
/[0-9]\@+@\S+\.\S+/
```

...but that's not right. I have been looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-can-you-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript), but can't quite figure out how to combine the numeric checks before the `@` with the email validator.

Ultimately I need a function that returns true if the string matches my pattern, and false otherwise.

Example string: `8015551234@foobar.com`

Comment: Do you have sample strings? I'm guessing you're trying to match phone number emails? If that's the case you can use `^\d{10}@\S+\.\S+$`

Comment: Thank you ctwheels, that looks right. Can you post your answer as such?

Comment: Try `^[0-9]{10}@` https://regex101.com/r/Ie5Vkv/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var r = /^\d{10}@\S+\.\S+$/,
    a = [
          '801555123@foobar.com',   // Too short
          '80155512341@foobar.com', // Too long
          'notNumbers@foobar.com', 
          '8015551234@foobar.com'   // Just right
        ]

a.forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(r.test(s))
})
```

#### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `\d{10}` Match exactly 10 digits
- `@` Match this literally
- `\S+` Match one or more non-whitespace characters
- `\.` Match a dot literally
- `\S+` Match one or more non-whitespace characters
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

Use the following RegEx:

```
/(?<=(\s|^))[0-9]{10}\@+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+/
```

See the [live demo (Regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/qraqdA/4).

If you do not require whitespace before the digit sequence (ie. if these digits needn't make up the whole local name [part before the `@`]) drop the lookbehind part (`(?<=\s*)`)

**Explanation**

- Checking for 10 digits before the `@`.
- Checking for a whitespace character or the start of the string before the number portion using negative lookbehind.
- Checking for a syntactically well-formed domain name after the at sign

**Notes**

- 'Syntactically well-formed' should be understood as absolutely low-level: Domain names are subject to various constraints that are not validated (eg. ending with a top-level domain). Regexen would be the wrong tool for this.
- The check for the domain portion does not cater for internationalised domain names. Have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2071250/) to get an idea.

**Code Embedding**

Turn the regex into a test code as follows:

```
[
      '123456789@example.com            '
    , '12345678901@example.com          '
    , 'a1234567890@example.com          '
    , 'whatever@example.com             '
    , '1234567890@example.com           '
    , '1234567890@gargamel.smurf.com    '
    , ' 1234567890@a.strange.domain.name.but.hey.if.it.gets.resolved....org'     
].map ( function ( sample ) {
    return /(?<=(\s|^))[0-9]{10}\@+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+/.test(sample);
});
```