# How can I avoid selecting email Ids with a particular domain name with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of e-mail ids among which I have to select only those which do not have **ruba.com** as domain name with regex. For examples, if I have ads@gmail.com, dgh@rubd.com and ert@**ruba**.com, then my regular expression should select first two Ids. What should be the regular expression for this problem?

I have tried with two expressions:

**[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[^(ruba)]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+** 
and
**[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[^r][^u][^b][^a]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+**

None of the above two was able to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Why do you want to use regex here? Why not just parse the email, and then check the domain against a blacklist? (That second parse can use a regex, but it'll be a really simple one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by email ID you mean the part before the `@` symbol, otherwise that would be a full email address.

```
.+(?=@)(?!@ruba\.com)
```

- `.` the dot character is a special symbol for regex engines
  and it is used to capture everything
- `*` also known as [Kleene plus](https://regexone.com/lesson/kleene_operators) says you want to capture one or more instances of the preceding symbol, in our case `.`; basically you are saying "give me every char"
- `(?=@)` is a positive lookahead, i.e. a special search feature that makes sure that what follows is `@`; I'm using it to take the cursor to the position of `@` and "stop" capturing, otherwise `+` would go on indefinitely
- `(?!@ruba\.com)` is a negative lookahead, i.e. a special search feature that makes sure that what follows is not (`!`) `@ruba\.com`; I'm escaping the dot not to confuse it with the capture-all symbol I was talking before

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/qNA8vG/1/).

Comment: The problem is that `.+` will match all characters, even invalid characters that do not belong in an email.

Comment: Yes, valid point. But he didn't say those address needed to be validated first, since he said "I have a list of email ids...", so I didn't feel compelled to satisfy a requirement that wasn't stated. Then the email specification may be a little tricky, I'm not sure that just \w\.\- would do because [other chars are admitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address). But in the end, my solution won't work if by "ID" he means a full address.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative lookahead to ensure that you do not match the domain **ruba.com**.

The negative lookahead: `(?!rubd)` will match *against* anything that you want to exclude. Also, because emails typically have more than word characters (such as hyphens and periods), you would be better off using `[\w\.\-]` rather than just `\w`.

```
^[\w\.\-]+@(?!rubd)[\w\.\-]+\.(?:com|net|org|edu)$
```

## [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Yjd9C6/1)