# GET by Email fails when looking for Email with a "+"

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have an application that stores information about a person onto a database, but when I try to use the URL to `GET` a user based on their email address users with a `+` in their email cannot be found.

Example URL that returns person:

```
https://www.someURL.com/api/people/johnsmith@someemail.com
```

Example URL that **does not** return person (returns null):

```
https://www.someURL.com/api/people/jane+doe@someemail.com
```

Both emails are in the database as written in the URL so it does not appear to be a typo issue, and I am using postman to test the `GET` method. Why am I not able to find them, and how can I make it so that they can be found even with the `+` character?

[Working postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkVah.png)

[**NOT** working postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0coE.png)

When I search with id I am able to find the person so I know the person exists.

[Verification that person exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUJVB.png)

Comment: Do you have logic in your back end to prevent SQL injection? Is that logic stripping the '+' character?  Have you verified that the desired record actually exists in the database?

Comment: I have verified that the record exists as it should be. The problem I have found is not with the logic that we have created, but with grails itself. Grails replaces the `+` with a space when used in the URL.

Comment: `&#43; `https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm rewrite the `+` to all to be `&#43;` see if it works

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be: change your server implementaion from GET to POST and provide an email as a String parameter within the body of request. It'll prevent this and any similar issue with escaping special characters in URI.

If it's not possible, try to frame email address with a single **'** or double **"** quotes, depending on how your web server treats incoming request it may help as well.

Nice to know that "+" is not really a 'valid' character for a lot of email providers for a reason. For instance, Gmail will not let you to create an email address with anything but [A-z0-9] (alphanumeric) and dot (.) characters. I'm pretty sure they were tired of validating input emails with complex regular expression and just limited it to basic ones.

Comment: I believe grails converts the `+` in URL parameters to a space when pulling variables off the parameter map.

Comment: You are right about that. When checking my request on the back-end I did notice the added space to the emails.

Answer (score 1):

'+' is a reserved character in URIs, so in order to prevent it being interpreted as a space character you would need to [percent-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it. In your example, replace '+' with '%2B'.

```
https://www.someURL.com/api/people/jane%2Bdoe@someemail.com
```

There are other [characters that are allowed in email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address#2049510) but are reserved characters in URIs, so it would be best to percent-encode the whole email address, just in case.