# FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL return wrong

Tags: php

I used `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` for validating e-mail addresses from input for registering form and today I noticed there is a problem with this function, so it return `true` *( or valid)* for such a bad e-mail address:

```
$mail = "www.infod-s@google.com";
if (filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "is valid";
} else {
    echo "not valid";
}
```

I know can use `regex` but I want to know why it is defective?

Comment: That’s a perfectly valid email address...

Comment: @patrick `www.` and `dash` is valid?

Comment: Yes, why not? A ‘w’ for a computer is nothing different from any other letter from the alphabet. And a dash is no problem either. william-arthur@yahoo.com is fine, will.smith@google.com as well.

Comment: @patrick I used this address now on yahoo, see: `You can only use letters, numbers, periods (‘.’), and underscores (‘_’) in your username.` I know `.` is valid but I don't think `-` is valid in address, and also `www.` is a wrong for email address, some user think should write email with `www.`

Comment: I think that the answer posted here provides a pretty detailed answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address

Comment: Also on gmail: `Sorry, only letters (a-z) numbers (0-9) and periods (.)  are allowed`

Comment: Those validations is Yahoo and Gmails, they could say "just numbers" too if they wanted, as all those are valid characters in an email.. Having `www.` in front of an email is not treated as the "world wide web", i.e. a website, it's just characters which makes part of the email-address.