# How do I split a combo list in a large text file?

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, large-data, large-files

my problem is that I have a very large database of emails and passwords and I need to send it to a mysql database.

The .txt file format is something like this:

```
emailnumberone@gmail.com:password1
emailnumbertwo@gmail.com:password2
emailnumberthree@gmail.com:password3
emailnumberfour@gmail.com:password4
emailnumberfive@gmail.com:password5
```

My idea is to make a loop that takes the line and make it a variable, search the ":" and pick the text before, send it to the db and then the same with the after part of the line. How do I do this?

Comment: what is your problem? splitting? db-access? storage? file reading?

Comment: splitting @PatrickArtner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short program with some error handling:

Create demo data file:

```
t = """
emailnumberone@gmail.com:password1
emailnumbertwo@gmail.com:password2
emailnumberthree@gmail.com:password3
emailnumberfour@gmail.com:password4
emailnumberfive@gmail.com:password5
k
: """

with open("f.txt","w") as f: f.write(t)
```

Parse data / store:

```
def store_in_db(email,pw):
    # replace with db access code 
    # see    http://bobby-tables.com/python
    # for parametrized db code in python (or the API of your choice)
    print("stored: ", email, pw)


with open("f.txt") as r:
    for line in r:
        if line.strip():  # weed out empty lines
            try:
                email, pw = line.split(":",1) # even if : in pw: only split at 1st :
                if email.strip() and pw.strip(): # only if both filled
                    store_in_db(email,pw)
                else:
                    raise ValueError("Something is empty: '"+line+"'")

            except Exception as ex:
                print("Error: ", line, ex)
```

Output:

```
stored:  emailnumberone@gmail.com password1

stored:  emailnumbertwo@gmail.com password2

stored:  emailnumberthree@gmail.com password3

stored:  emailnumberfour@gmail.com password4

stored:  emailnumberfive@gmail.com password5

Error:  k
 not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
Error:  :  Something is empty: ': '
```

---

Edit: According to [What characters are allowed in an email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address) - a `':'` may be part of the first part of an email if quoted.

This would theoretically allow inputs as

```
`"Cool:Emailadress@google.com:coolish_password"`
```

which will get errors with this code. See [Talip Tolga Sans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53548860/7505395) for how to break down the splitting differently to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done through simple `split()` method of the strings in python.

```
>>> a = 'emailnumberone@gmail.com:password1'
>>> b = a.split(':')
>>> b
['emailnumberone@gmail.com', 'password1']
```

To accomodate  @PatrickArtner's complex password fail this can be done:

```
atLocation = a.find('@')
realSeperator = atLocation + a[atLocation:].find(':')
emailName = a[0:atLocation]
emailDomain = a[atLocation:realSeperator]
email = emailName + emailDomain
password = a[realSeperator + 1:]

print(email, password)

>>> emailnumberone@gmail.com com:plex:PassWord:fail
```

str.find() returns the first occurrence location of the given character in the given string. Emails can have `:` in their name field but they can not have `@`. So first locating the `@` then locating the `:` would give you the correct separation locations. After that splitting the string will be piece of cake.

Comment: `'emailnumberone@gmail.com:com:plex:PassWord:fail'`

Comment: `b = a.split(':',1)` ?   https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split  - I was more concerned about a password having a `:` in it .. I am unsure wether emails can actually contain a `:` - seems they could if quoted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address

Comment: from  [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) it says this about the local part so I made sure first  ':' is not in the local part "space and "(),:;<>@[\] characters are allowed with restrictions (they are only allowed inside a quoted string, as described in the paragraph below, and in addition, a backslash or double-quote must be preceded by a backslash);" However your solution is more elegant then mine

Comment: but the simple split(":",1) is less exact - it does not allow for any ":" in the local part even if quoted - yours got my upvote

Answer (score -1):

Open file as context manager (with open(...)), You can iterate over the lines with a for loop, then regex match(re Module)(or just split on ":") and use sqlite3 to insert your values to DB.

So the file:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        pass #manipulation
```

Sqlite3 Docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html