# Validating Email addresses in my google bigquery database by using mysql regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I am trying to validate **email addresses** in my google bigquery table.
I am using following query to do that but bigquery is throwing an error.
I am not sure what is wrong in my code. I found the regex for validation on below story:- [What characters are allowed in an email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address)

```
select email
FROM my table
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(email, regex)
```

here regex is the

[Perl's RFC2822 regex](https://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/full_regexp.txt)

Comment: Can you add the error message? it may due to the REGEXP expression or how your specify it. Notice `regex` should be quoted and with a character (`r`) before the quotes. Check [this example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains) about REGEXP in Standard SQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT email
FROM table
where email REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}'
```

Note that the last part `{2,6}` will limit the top domain name to only 6 characthers long, as pointed out by @smoore4.

```
SELECT email
FROM table
where email REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}'
```

This will only demand a minimum length of `2` from the top domain.

Comment: `` is really short for TLDs, see TLD list: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db ; valid/invalid addresses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples ; regex for RFC822 email address:  http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: Is this still working in BigQuery? This works in BigQuery `REGEXP_CONTAINS(email, r'^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$')`.

Comment: you should create your comment as an answer p13rr0m, imho

Comment: the last part about {2,6} is mostly ok but it will leave off new valid domains such as .shopping, .digital, .computer, etc

Answer (score 0):

I think this is cleaner...

```
SELECT email 
FROM table 
where REGEXP_CONTAINS(email, r"@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+")
```

Comment: This is not correct. For example, email@email.com@ and @email.com are not valid email addresses but would work according to this regex.