# Query to return only rows that have valid emails and output only the email

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I have a old table that has applicant info including the person who interviewed them `Name|Phone|Email|Addr|Interv|IntervEmail`

unfortunately the interviewer emails are a mess. Some blank some have phone numbers some have spaces or other special characters like `this.is.a.mess@anydamnplace.com / 999-222-5555 home` or `home 999-222-5555, this.is.a.mess@anydamnplace.com`

What I would like is be able to get all rows with interviewer emails from the table but only the email and not the other junk.

any help appreciated

example From this

```
user   | home_phone | applicant_email           | addr      | intrvwr_nm | intrvwr_email
-------+------------+---------------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
Jane   | 1234567890 | someemail@anydamplace.com | 123 here  | Jeff       | jeff@surething.net / 321589364
Larry  | 1234567890 | someemail@anydamplace.com | 123 there | Eddie      | gjfgn@anotherplace.net / 2321.654.9872
harry  | 1234567890 | someemail@anydamplace.com | 456 here  | Murray     | Admissions Field Representative/murray@anotherplace.com/212-222-1111
Carrie | 1234567890 | someemail@anydamplace.com | 456 there | Del        | dely@school.edu
Joe    | 1234567890 | someemail@anydamplace.com | 123 here  | James      | 1234567890/sometext, this.is.a.mess@anydamnplace.com
```

To this

```
user   | home_phone | applicant_email           | addr      | intrvwr_nm | intrvwr_email
-------+------------+---------------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
Jane   | 1234567890 | someemail@anydamplace.com | 123 here  | Jeff       | jeff@surething.net
Larry  | 1234567890 | someemail@anydamplace.com | 123 there | Eddie      | gjfgn@anotherplace.net
harry  | 1234567890 | someemail@anydamplace.com | 456 here  | Murray     | murray@anotherplace.com
Carrie | 1234567890 | someemail@anydamplace.com | 456 there | Del        | dely@school.edu
Joe    | 1234567890 | someemail@anydamplace.com | 123 here  | James      | this.is.a.mess@anydamnplace.com
```

Comment: Is this a one-time thing?  How many rows are you looking at?  This might be something more well suited for a platform that supports regular expressions.

Comment: Yes most likely one time deal so we can copy clean data to new table. it has 1981 rows atm

Comment: however, we might need it for other tables. It would probably be easier to put it in an excel sheet and do a regexp (which I would not know how to either now) but we might need something similar for all the old tables

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Do all of the email addresses in the garbage rows have a delimiting character (such as a space) on either end of the address?  If so, something in t-sql could probably be created fairly easily.  If not, not even sure regexp could take care of it...

Comment: I added an example of what it looks like now and what we would like the output to be

Comment: Given the total trainwreck of that data and that you only have 1,981 rows I would just manually edit this. Any query you write is going to be fraught with issues because that data is a mess. There are just too many variables with this type of data.

Comment: Agreed.  Just from the sample data posted you have no way of programatically consistently distinguishing an email address.

Comment: I agree with Sean Lange here. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address a slash is allowed in an email address, so it needs common sense to tell whether the email address is `'Representative/murray@anotherplace.com'` or just `'murray@anotherplace.com'`.

Comment: Old data slashes most likely not an issue

Comment: What's your timeline? This looks like an _awesome_ project for a summer intern....

Comment: Suggest you read about this madness first - [the 100% way to validate](https://medium.com/hackernoon/the-100-correct-way-to-validate-email-addresses-7c4818f24643)

Answer (score 3):

Try running this query. It would catch most of the valid email address:

```
SELECT a.email 
FROM
(
SELECT value as email  
FROM applicant_Table  
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(intrvwr_email, ' ') 
) as a
where a.email like '%_@__%.__%'
```

Please take into account that:

1. This only works for SQL Server 2016 or above.
2. The delimiter is a space.

You can add more columns to the query (like the row ID) so you get to know in which row is stored every email address you're getting.

Comment: that returns rows no emails at all.
and SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE email LIKE '%_@__%.__%'
returns the other junk with the emai
I just need the rows with an email and the cell should only have the email itself not the phone or other stuff

Comment: that actually worked good except when there was no space between the email and junk returned emailherer@yahoo.com/(123) instead of emailherer@yahoo.com/(123) 456789

Comment: @CrashWave Just a minor twist on the answer above (+1)  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c81128c5f708f20ca6a702d6a048b9aa

Comment: @john-cappelletti Your minor twist soled our problem. THANK YOU