# How to validate an email address in Go

Tags: email, go, email-validation

I have checked the StackOverflow and couldn't find any question that answers **how to validate email in Go Language**.

After some research, I figured out and solved it as per my need.

I have this **regex** and **Go function**, which work fine:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(isEmailValid("test44@gmail.com")) // true
    fmt.Println(isEmailValid("test$@gmail.com")) // true -- expected "false" 
}


// isEmailValid checks if the email provided is valid by regex.
func isEmailValid(e string) bool {
    emailRegex := regexp.MustCompile("^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$")
    return emailRegex.MatchString(e)
}
```

The problem is that **it accepts the special characters that I don't want**. I tried to use some from other languages' "regex" expression, but it throws the error **"unknown escape"** in debug.

Could anyone give me a good regex or any fast solution (pkg) that works with GoLang?

Comment: https://github.com/goware/emailx

Comment: https://github.com/badoux/checkmail

Comment: 1. The language is called Go. 2. Regex and e-mail addresses do not mix well no matter what language.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The standard lib has email parsing and validation built in, simply use: [`mail.ParseAddress()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/mail/#ParseAddress).

A simple "is-valid" test:

```
func valid(email string) bool {
    _, err := mail.ParseAddress(email)
    return err == nil
}
```

Testing it:

```
for _, email := range []string{
    "good@exmaple.com",
    "bad-example",
} {
    fmt.Printf("%18s valid: %t\n", email, valid(email))
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MjOg6JWkfd6)):

```
  good@exmaple.com valid: true
       bad-example valid: false
```

**NOTE:**

The [`net/mail`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/mail) package implements and follows the [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) specification (and extension by [RFC 6532](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6532.html)). This means a seemingly bad email address like `bad-example@t` is accepted and parsed by the package because it's valid according to the spec. `t` may be a valid local domain name, it does not necessarily have to be a public domain. `net/mail` does not check if the domain part of the address is a public domain, nor that it is an existing, reachable public domain.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's working on most of the cases. Still, I have some issues with the following invalid emails:
"email@example.com (Joe Smith)",
"email@example"

Comment: @RiyazKhan Those email addresses are valid according to [RFC 5322](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322). The `net/mail` package implements RFC 5322 compliant email address parsing.

Comment: got it, as in the doc for RFC 5322, it's written that it's checking domain. Here is [screenshot](https://paste.pics/e1dbbbeeee708fdd68fab6583eae4f7d), then why it's failing for the "email@example" address.

Comment: @RiyazKhan `example` is a valid domain, just like `example.com`. It does not necessarily have to designate a public domain, it may be a local domain of a local network. As to the `(Joe Smith)` part: it's a comment and it may be anywhere in the email, see [Wikipedia: Email address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address). Trust me, the `net/mail` package can parse email addresses better, faster and more reliably than your custom solution can.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid email
"bad-example@t"

Comment: @tile According to [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html) it is valid. `t` may be a valid local domain name. As mentioned in the above comments, the domain may be a local domain, it does not necessarily have to be a public domain.

Comment: this method ParseAddress also accepts "good <good@email.com>" as a valid string. Might not be what you want.

Comment: @Duck1337 Yes, because that format is used to specify the person name and email address. `good` is the person name, `good@email.com` is the email address in your example. It's perfectly valid by RFC 5322.

Comment: can `my@you` be a valid email account? `mail.ParseAddress()` is returning `true`

Comment: @MudasirYounas Yes, it can be. All email addresses are valid where `mail.ParseAddress()` returns `nil` error. No need to ask for every one of them.

Comment: even `a@b` get passwd, this is not very good for real email.

Comment: @Eric Please read comments above. It's valid, `b` may be a _local_ domain, so in a local network `a@b` can be used as a valid email address.

Answer (score 18):

The above approach from @icza is nice, however, if we use it in login/signup form validation, many people will enter a partial or incorrect email address, which will create a bunch of **invalid records in production**. Furthermore, *who knows we might get killed because of that*.

Therefore, I went to the regex solution to **validate standard emails**:

**Here is the code:**

```
func isEmailValid(e string) bool {
    emailRegex := regexp.MustCompile(`^[a-z0-9._%+\-]+@[a-z0-9.\-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$`)
    return emailRegex.MatchString(e)
}
```

**Test Cases:**

```
fmt.Println(isEmailValid("test44@gmail.com"))         // true 
fmt.Println(isEmailValid("bad-email"))               // false
fmt.Println(isEmailValid("test44$@gmail.com"))      // false
fmt.Println(isEmailValid("test-email.com"))        // false
fmt.Println(isEmailValid("test+email@test.com"))  // true
```

Comment: even the most rotten answer of SO acknowledge that $ is accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049510/4466350 https://play.golang.org/p/iI2GeEmHRzE

Comment: Believe me, `mail.ParseAddress()` does a better job than what you can. It accepts local domain, but tell me, are you sure `this-surely-doesnt-exist-just-showing-this-will-pass@nowhereland.cum` is a better "valid" email than `good@mydomain`? You should implement and require email verification anyway. Else simply validating if the email address is syntactically correct is worth close to nothing.

Comment: @icza why `mail.ParseAddress()` is passing your bad example email `this-surely-doesnt-exist-just-showing-this-will-pass@nowhereland.cum` ?. Who cares about the local domain in production, can you register an email address like a local domain in any email provider service?

Comment: @RiyazKhan Yes, you can't use a local domain at `gmail.com`, because `gmail.com` is a public domain. But if a company operates an email service for its workers, yes, you can use (or you may _only_ use) a local domain there.

Comment: This misses non-ASCII characters, which are valid in the domain name part and the TLD. Also, there are ASCII TLDs with length greater than 4 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains). And, even if you have a valid email, you still need to check it's actually owned by your user. So you HAVE to require email verification.

Answer (score 2):

Since I find regexp hard to read I prefer readable boring code. For example:

```
// Accepts at least the x@y.zz pattern.
func isEmailAddress(v string) bool {
    if v == "" {
        return false
    }
    if containsWhitespace(v) {
        return false
    }

    iAt := strings.IndexByte(v, '@')
    if iAt == -1 {
        return false
    }

    localPart := v[:iAt]
    if localPart == "" {
        return false
    }

    domain := v[iAt+1:]
    if domain == "" {
        return false
    }

    iDot := strings.IndexByte(domain, '.')
    if iDot == -1 || iDot == 0 || iDot == len(domain)-1 {
        return false
    }

    if strings.Index(domain, "..") != -1 {
        return false
    }

    iTLD := strings.LastIndexByte(domain, '.')
    return 2 <= len([]rune(domain[iTLD+1:]))
}

func containsWhitespace(v string) bool {
    for _, r := range v {
        if unicode.IsSpace(r) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This external package [govalidator](https://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator) is doing the job perfectly for me.

```
import (
  "fmt"
  "github.com/asaskevich/govalidator"
)
```

```
func main() {
    d := govalidator.IsEmail("helloworld@") 
    fmt.Println(d) // false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function `IsEmail` which is based on the standard library [mail](https://pkg.go.dev/net/mail#ParseAddress)

```golang
func IsEmail(email string) bool {
  emailAddress, err := mail.ParseAddress(email)
  return err == nil && emailAddress.Address == email
}
```

Test cases:

```golang
func main() {
  fmt.Println("'hello@world.com'", IsEmail("hello@world.com")) // true
  fmt.Println("'asd <hello@world.com>'", IsEmail("asd <hello@world.com>")) // false
  fmt.Println("'a@b'", IsEmail("a@b")) // true
}
```

Comment: You sir, deserve cookie for coming up with a way to make sure inputs with the "name" doesn't pass with `emailAddress.Address == email` 

Comment: foo@bar passes as correct email address

Answer (score 1):

The `isValid` function validates and normalizes email addresses. If the email contains non-ASCII characters, it converts them to Punycode. The function then checks whether the email meets established criteria for a valid email address, enabling support for any language.

And, then it can be converted back to its original language using the `idna.ToUnicode` function. This reversibility ensures that internationalized domain names and email addresses can be stored and processed in a standardized form, yet still presented to the user in a readable and understandable format.

I think this is the best one that can be found on this website for email checks, bar none.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/net/idna"
)

func isValid(email string) interface{} {
    // Check the overall length of the email address
    if len(email) > 320 {
        return fmt.Errorf("email length exceeds 320 characters")
    }

    // Transform the local part to lowercase for case-insensitive unique storage
    parts := strings.Split(strings.ToLower(email), "@")
    if len(parts) != 2 {
        return fmt.Errorf("email must contain a single '@' character")
    }
    localPart, domainPart := parts[0], parts[1]

    // Check for empty local or domain parts
    if len(localPart) == 0 || len(domainPart) == 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("local or domain part cannot be empty in the email")
    }

    // Check for consecutive special characters in the local part
    prevChar := rune(0)
    for _, char := range localPart {
        if strings.ContainsRune("!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~.", char) {
            if char == prevChar && char != '-' {
                return fmt.Errorf("consecutive special characters '%c' are not allowed in the local part", char)
            }
        }
        prevChar = char
    }

    // Check for spaces
    if strings.ContainsAny(email, " ") {
        return fmt.Errorf("spaces are not allowed in the email")
    }

    // Check the length of the local part and the domain part
    if len(localPart) > 64 || len(domainPart) > 255 {
        return fmt.Errorf("local part or domain part length exceeds the limit in the email")
    }

    // Convert international domain to ASCII (Punycode) only if needed
    asciiDomain, err := idna.ToASCII(domainPart)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to convert domain to ASCII: %s", err)
    }

    // Convert international local part to ASCII (Punycode) only if needed
    asciiLocal, err := idna.ToASCII(localPart)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to convert local part to ASCII: %s", err)
    }

    // Check that the domain labels do not start or end with special characters and TLD is alphabetic
    domainLabels := strings.Split(asciiDomain, ".")
    for i, label := range domainLabels {
        // Check first and last character of each label
        if !strings.ContainsAny("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789", string(label[0])) ||
            !strings.ContainsAny("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789", string(label[len(label)-1])) {
            return fmt.Errorf("domain labels must not start or end with special characters in the email")
        }

        // Check label length
        if len(label) > 63 {
            return fmt.Errorf("domain label length exceeds the limit in the email")
        }

        // Validate that the TLD is alphabetic
        if i == len(domainLabels)-1 && !strings.HasPrefix(label, "xn--") {
            decodedTLD, err := idna.ToUnicode(label)
            if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("failed to decode TLD: %s", err)
            }
            isAlpha := true
            for _, ch := range decodedTLD {
                if (ch < 'a' || ch > 'z') && (ch < 'A' || ch > 'Z') {
                    isAlpha = false
                    break
                }
            }
            if !isAlpha {
                return fmt.Errorf("TLD must be alphabetic in the email")
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the fully converted email
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s@%s", asciiLocal, asciiDomain)
}

func main() {
    // Standard ASCII email address (Valid)
    fmt.Println(isValid("test@example.com")) // Should return "test@example.com"

    // Unicode in local part (Valid)
    fmt.Println(isValid("tést@example.com")) // Should return Punycode-converted email

    // Punycode-encoded domain (IDNA) (Valid)
    fmt.Println(isValid("test@xn--fsqu00a.xn--0zwm56d")) // Should return "test@xn--fsqu00a.xn--0zwm56d"

    // Unicode in domain part (Valid)
    fmt.Println(isValid("test@例子.测试")) // Should return Punycode-converted domain

    // Unicode in both local and domain parts (Valid)
    fmt.Println(isValid("tést@例子.测试")) // Should return fully Punycode-converted email

    // Cyrillic script in local part (Valid)
    fmt.Println(isValid("тест@пример.ру")) // Should return fully Punycode-converted email

    // Arabic script in local part (Valid)
    fmt.Println(isValid("اختبار@مثال.اختبار")) // Should return fully Punycode-converted email

    // Hebrew script in local part (Valid)
    fmt.Println(isValid("בדיקה@דוגמה.בדיקה")) // Should return fully Punycode-converted email

    // Punycode-encoded local part and domain (Valid)
    fmt.Println(isValid("xn--e1aybc@xn--80akhbyknj4f.xn--p1ai")) // Should return "xn--e1aybc@xn--80akhbyknj4f.xn--p1ai"

    // Various other languages (All should be Valid)
    fmt.Println(isValid("測試@例子.測試"))   // Should return fully Punycode-converted email (Chinese)
    fmt.Println(isValid("テスト@例.テスト"))  // Should return fully Punycode-converted email (Japanese)
    fmt.Println(isValid("테스트@예시.테스트")) // Should return fully Punycode-converted email (Korean)

    // Email with consecutive special characters in local part (Invalid)
    fmt.Println(isValid("test..test@example.com")) // Should return an error

    // Email with special characters at the beginning or end of the local part (Invalid)
    fmt.Println(isValid(".test@example.com")) // Should return an error
    fmt.Println(isValid("test.@example.com")) // Should return an error

    // Email with space (Invalid)
    fmt.Println(isValid("test test@example.com")) // Should return an error

    // Email with no local part (Invalid)
    fmt.Println(isValid("@example.com")) // Should return an error

    // Email with no domain part (Invalid)
    fmt.Println(isValid("test@")) // Should return an error

    // Email with empty string (Invalid)
    fmt.Println(isValid("")) // Should return an error

    // Email exceeding 320 character limit (Invalid)
    fmt.Println(isValid(strings.Repeat("a", 320) + "@example.com")) // Should return an error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method implementation example:

```
var emailRegexp = regexp.MustCompile("^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$")
```

This was in the same package as where I created my struct

```
type EmailInputRegistration struct {
    Email           string
}
```

And then for handling errors:

```
func (in EmailInputRegistration) Validate() error {
    if !emailRegexp.MatchString(in.Email) {
        return fmt.Errorf("%w: email invalid", ErrValidation)
    }
    //any other exception handling...

    return nil
}
```

Ideally, this EmailInputRegistration should be refactored to include all the data needed for Registering such as email, user, password, etc.