# Regular expression for email but disallow address ending with `.co`

Tags: regex, email

I have this regular expression for valid email addresses which works well: `^(?=[\w\s])\s*[-+.'\w]+@[-.\w]+\.[-.\w]{2,}\s*$`

However, users are sometimes entering an address like "john@gmail.co". I could exclude "co" from my regex, but I still want to allow "john@example.co.uk", [see here](https://regex101.com/r/DdnIt9/1).

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) but I don't know how to include that in the part `[-.\w]{2,}` of my current expression.

How can I alter my regular expression to disallow ".co" at the end of an email address?

Comment: A number of other nonalphabetic characters such as `*` and `&` are allowed in the local part. `\w` is imprecise because it allows underscore in the domain part. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write the pattern without the lookahead at the start as:

```php
^\s*[-+.'\w]+@\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*\.(?!co\s*$)[a-z]{2,}\s*$
```

Note that `[-+.'\w]` and `\w` limits the range of valid email addresses.

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\s*[-+.'\w]+@` Match optional whitespace chars and repeat any listed chars in the character class until matching @
- `\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*` After the @ start with matching 1+ word chars and optionally repeat either `.` or `-` and 1+ word chars
- `\.(?!co\s*$)` Match a dot and use a negative lookahead asserting not `co` and optional whitespace chars until the end of strinng
- `[a-z]{2,}\s*` Match 2 or more chars a-z and optional whitespace chars
- `$` End of string

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IMpyCn/1)

If you don't want to allow matching leading whitespace chars, you can omit `\s*` from the start and the end of the pattern.