# Replace function is very slow in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, replace

I am trying to execute the query as below in SQL Server but it is very slow due to the `Replace` function, can anyone help in optimizing the query to run very fast

```sql
SELECT 
    dbo.Orders.OrigID
FROM
    dbo.Orders
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.OrderedReports ON dbo.Orders.OrigID = dbo.OrderedReports.OrderID
WHERE 
    (REPLACE(Orders.Email, '^^', '''') = 'Khengtjinyap@gmail.com')
```

Comment: It is indeed very slow. There's not a great deal you can do about it with just this query. If your data must contain ^^ and this query is overall important to you, I'd suggest adding a new persisted computed column such as NormalisedEmail that does this replace operation _once_ rather than every time you run the query.

Comment: You are using `REPLACE` in your `WHERE`, making the query non-SARGable. If you want to improve the performance, you'll need to add a (`PERSISTED`) computed column to your table `Orders` that has the `Email` value with the caret (`^`) characters replaced, and then you would index and query that column.

Comment: On a separate note, [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable. Also, your `ON` clause is missing the equals (`=`) is missing.

Comment: Why on earth do you have `^^` represent single quote anyway? I'd be suspicious that this is a sign that somewhere isn't using parameterised queries and is using this to hack around the fact that the quote is the literal string delimiter

Comment: You can simply remove the entire `REPLACE`, because `'Khengtjinyap@gmail.com'` doesn't contain a single quote, so no value containing `'^^'` will be equal to `'Khengtjinyap@gmail.com'` after the `REPLACE`

Comment: Can you help to define "fast" and "slow" for this problem?  And roughly what plan shape you get which is too slow?

Comment: If you replace on the other side of the `=` you'll likely get better performance, especially if you always search for a specific address

Answer (score 2):

One simple long term fix here would be to simply remove the `^^` symbols from the email *before* you insert the data.  In order to deal with the email data which already exists in the `Orders` table, you could do the following one-time update:

```sql
UPDATE Orders
SET Email = REPLACE(Email, '^^', '')
WHERE Email LIKE '%^^%';
```

You could also create a new column which contains the cleaned up email addresses.  Once you have made this change, just use a direct equality comparison in your query, which can now also use an index on the `Email` column.

Comment: OP has `REPLACE(Email, '^^', '''')`

Comment: @Face Check the RHS of the comparison...it will never be true.

Comment: The first part of an email address is allowed `'` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address. So OP may actually want that