# Regular expression for email in flex

Tags: java, lexical-analysis, jflex

I am trying to wirte a regular expression for emails in JFlex. So far I tried with this

```
L=[a-zA-Z_]+
D=[0-9]+    
email=[^(.+)@(\S+)$]
%{
    public String lexeme;
%}
%%
{L}({L}|{D})* {lexeme=yytext(); return Identi;}
("(-"{D}+")")|{D}+ {lexeme=yytext(); return Number;}
{email} {lexeme=yytext(); return Email;}
 . {return ERROR;}
```

When I test with an email, the lexer is not matching any email.
How to match email?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
alphaNumeric=({L}+|{L}+{D}+)+
email={alphaNumeric}"@"{alphaNumeric}"."({L}+|{L}+"."{L}+)
```

This is the regular expression

Comment: This is a terrible regex for matching emails. It rejects *many* valid email addresses.

Comment: And which is the best Regex for matching emails?

Comment: The best pattern is the least restrictive one possible which still likely catches the wrong type of data (for example names, phone numbers or physical addresses):`.+@.+\..+`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression

Comment: Even without getting into [unicode/internationalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email), you miss tons of very common emails, like `john.smith@gmail.com` or `john+smith@gmail.com` or `john@mail-server.com`. There are *way* more characters in emails that just the alphanumeric range: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049510/229044