# Grep Regex to match emails with single top level domains

Tags: regex, bash, grep, regex-negation

I am writing a bash file that matches emails using regex. But I only want to match emails with single top level domain NOT emails with multiple ones.

For example those emails should match:

```
example@example.com
example@gmail.com
john@smith.org
```

But this email should NOT match because it has 2 top level domains .co.fr

```
example@example.co.fr
```

I tried the following:

`grep -E -o '[A-Za-z0-9.]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}(?!\.[A-Za-z])' log.txt > mails.txt`

But the `(?!\.[A-Za-z])` part is not working with bash, my understanding that it negates the match if it finds a second domain after the first dot.

it's working fine when I try it on online tools: https://regex101.com/r/H4ftC3/1

I also tried use $ at the end: `[A-Za-z0-9.]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$` but this one doesn't match anything.

How can I match only single top level domains?

Thanks

Comment: Note local part (to left of `@`) can be much more complicated than letters, digits and period.

Comment: This should work: `^[^@]+@[^.]+\.[^.]+$` https://regex101.com/r/IrTwy6/1

Comment: See http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html for a regexp that matches emails. You may need to tweak it based on the tool you're using for that matching. I personally use `(addr ~ /^[0-9a-zA-Z._%+-]+@[0-9a-zA-Z.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/) && (addr ~ /^.*[a-zA-Z]{2}.*@.*[a-zA-Z]{2}.*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/)` in awk with the second check just to get rid of strings like `x@y.co` that are technically valid email addresses but are more likely just noise in the input. It could probably be done in one regexp but I was lazy,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

```
grep -P -i "[\w+-.]+@[\w+-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" file.txt 

-P - option for advanced Perl like regex (allows using \w)
-i - ignore case (matches @xyz.com ou @xyz.COM)
```

For input file: `file.txt`

```
    example@gmail.com
    john@smith.org
    example@example.co.gr
    john@zcal.co
    john.smith@zcal.co
    john.smith@zcal.com.br
    john.de-smith@zcal.com.br
    john.de-smith@hotmail.com
    john_de_smith@hotmail.com
    john.de-smith@hotmail.AG
    john.de-smith@dept.hotmail.AG
```

Resulting:

```
    example@gmail.com
    john@smith.org
    john@zcal.co
    john.smith@zcal.co
    john.de-smith@hotmail.com
    john_de_smith@hotmail.com
    john.de-smith@hotmail.AG
```

### No fancy characters, please.

In order to answer your question it's important to make some assumptions.

1. E-mails *regex* are tricky, and you already read this answer on Stackoverflow ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2049502/4464748)), as well as this  article on Wikipedia ([2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part)).
2. Your e-mails *local part* (a.k.a. user name) only have the following characters: letter from `A-Za-z`, numbers from `0` to `9`, special characters `+-_` (a *very reduced* of the allowed set), and dot `.` in the middle.
3. No fancy `utf-8` or `utf-16` characters. Not even latin ones (e.g. `ç`, `ñ`)

This assumption represents 99,73% of all e-mail addresses known so far.

### Allowed chars

`username_allowed_chars = [A-Za-z0-9_+-.]`

In fact, I assume you're using **gnu grep**, therefore you may use `grep -P` (perl style regex) and the following set `\w` which is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, thence:

`username_allowed_chars = [\w+-.]`

As for the domain part, remove `+` and dot `.`, thence:

`domain_allowed_chars = [\w-]`

Finally we will use `+` for `1 or more` repetitions of chars.

```
grep -P -i "[\w+-.]+@[\w+-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" file.txt
```

I'll break this regex in parts. First the *character set* `\w`  that is used extensively.

- `\w` - Translates do `[A-Za-z0-9_]` **word indentifier** a.k.a. allowed chars for variable names, in programming parlance. In practice disallows punctuations and other unusual characters in e-mail user name;
- `\.` - literal dot `.`;
- `[\w+-.]+`- One or more of these identifiers, and **includes** the **period** or *dot* in user names. e.g. `john.doe@gmail.com`.
- `@` - literal `@` to separate username from domain name.
- `[a-z]{2,}$` - No less than two lowercase letters up to the end of the string (marked by `$`).

#### References

(1) [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2049502/4464748)

(2) [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part)

Comment: Nor RFC compliant. The left part of `@` can be far more complicated

Comment: No need `-P`, `-E` is sufficient here and most portable

Answer (score 0):

##### Input file

```
$ cat file
example@example.com
example@gmail.com
john@smith.org
example@example.co.fr
```

##### With `grep`:

```
grep -v '@.*\..*\.' file
example@example.com
example@gmail.com
john@smith.org
```

- `-v` invert the matches

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Regex | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `@` | Match the character “@” literally |
| `.*` | Match a any character except newline Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) |
| `\.` | Match the character “.” literally |
| `.*` | see upper |
| `\.` | Match the character “.” literally |

Comment: I think you need `LANG=C grep ...` to ensure `[\w-]` has that meaning

Comment: Why ? UTF8 should be allowed AFAIK

Comment: There's so many characters allowed in [`RFC 2822`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822)

Comment: my comment related to the description you provided, not to what characters are allowed in a domain name (but see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1 and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.5 )

Comment: Nitpicking here =) Added better explanation

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`

```
$ grep -E '^\S+@\w+\.\w+$' input_file
example@example.com
example@gmail.com
john@smith.org
```

View [demo](https://regex101.com/r/u8PTEE/1)

Comment: Nor RFC compliant. The left part of `@` can be far more complicated

Comment: @GillesQuénot If it is more complicated than `\S+` can handle, then OP can show it in question so it can be addressed.

Comment: @GillesQuénot In fact my answer is not RFC compliant.  That's why I assumed a reduced set of characters, only \w eq. [A-Za-z0-9_] and [.+-], instead of [A-Za-z0-9_.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~], that are RFC compliant but very rare in practice. Sometimes pi = 3.1416 instead of pi = π , for that matter.