# Why these input validations are not working? (contact us form via PHP & HTML & SMTP server & PHPmailer)

Tags: php, html, validation, phpmailer, contact-form

I'm using **PHP & HTML & SMTP server & PHPmailer** to create a contact us form with user input validation. But after pressing "submit" button it gives me an error:

> Invalid address: (From):
> Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: Invalid address: (From): in C:\xampp\htdocs\RESPONSIVE
> SITE3_2\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php:1324
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\RESPONSIVE SITE3_2\send-email.php(74): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->setFrom('', '')
> #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\RESPONSIVE SITE3_2\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php on line 1324

**PHP code**:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
// $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
$message = $_POST["message"];

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
} 

if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/", $email)) {
    $emailErr = "Email should contain only letters, numbers, and underscores";
}

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail->Port = 587;

require_once 'config.php';
$mail->Username = SMTP_USERNAME;
$mail->Password = SMTP_PASSWORD;

$mail->setFrom($email, $name);
$mail->addAddress("myemail@gmail.com", "Ads");

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body =  "Name: $name\nEmail: $email\n\n$message";

$mail->send();

header("Location: sent.html");
?>
```

**HTML code**

```
<form method="POST" action="send-email.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name*">
    
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email*">
    <span class="error" style="color:red"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>

    
    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message*"></textarea>
    
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button">Start</button>
</form>
```

I was trying different tutorials - unsuccessful.
I need this form to

- validate user input and only numbers and letters are allowed to insert (mail field)
- if data is not valid error message must appear under the input field

I'm a very new to this, please explain in very simple words :)

Comment: Even if the validation returns an error, you still try to send the mail. You need to check it with an `if` statement and skip all the sending code.

Comment: In my code "preg_match" doesn't work at all (I can input URL, for example, and it takes that as valid)

Comment: How do you know? After trying to send the email you redirect to `sent.html`, so you don't show `$emailErr`.

Comment: It works here: https://ideone.com/1c0eiB

Comment: How to make so that $emailErr is shown and no redirection?

Comment: Like I said, use an `if` statement. `if (empty($emailErr)) { code that sends the email and redirects } else { code that shows $emailErr; }`

Comment: You do realise that PHPMailer has built-in validation, and `addAddress` will return false (or throw an exception) if an address you submit is not valid. You really don't need to roll your own; I'd recommend just deleting that `preg_match`. Generally you're missing any error checking, so perhaps take a look at [the contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Diagnosis**

If either of the validation `if` statements are true, all that will happen is it sets a string variable `$emailErr`.

Then the code exits the `if` block again, and the script just carries on its merry way and tries to send the email anyway. There is no logic in the code which prevents this.

And at the end of that, `$emailErr` never gets used because the code is redirecting the user to a different HTML page which cannot involve that variable.

**Solution**

You need some extra logic to tell the code to skip the email-sending part if any of the validations failed. One way to achieve this neatly is quite easy, using a "flag" variable.

For example:

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
// $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
$message = $_POST["message"];
$valid = true;
$emailErr = "";

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    $valid = false;
} 

if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/", $email)) {
    $emailErr = "Email should contain only letters, numbers, and underscores";
    $valid = false;
}

//only send if all validations passed:
if ($valid == true)
{
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

  $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;

  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

  $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
  $mail->Port = 587;

  require_once 'config.php';
  $mail->Username = SMTP_USERNAME;
  $mail->Password = SMTP_PASSWORD;

  $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
  $mail->addAddress("myemail@gmail.com", "Ads");

  $mail->Subject = $subject;
  $mail->Body =  "Name: $name\nEmail: $email\n\n$message";
  $mail->send();

  header("Location: sent.html");
}
else
{
  echo $emailErr;
}
```

P.S. As an aside, your regular expression is too restrictive - see [What characters are allowed in an email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address) . And since you're using `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` already, you shouldn't really need it in any case.

Comment: Many thanks!!! U made my wife happy :D